# MS CA Exit Module Code or Tutorial

Tags: pki

I'm struggling to find examples/explanations of coding a MS Certificate Authority exit module.

If anybody has any help or resources they can point me at I'd be grateful.

Comment: This appears to be an almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208057/ms-ca-exit-module-code-or-tutorial. I'd like to close one of them - which one would you like me to close?

Comment: Heh, I'd say standard practice is to keep the earlier one. :-P

Comment: I followed through on my own advice. If you want, feel free to reopen it and close it yourself so it's got your name attached to the closing message instead. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this article will help you? [Writing Custom Exit Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388214.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 SDK contains a sample in directory security/certificateservices/exit/c++/.

You can download only the sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/certificateservices/exit/c%2B%2B/WindowsServer2008R2

Comment: BTW, downloading a single folder instead of the whole repository requires a trick, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo