# Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo

Tags: git, file, github, directory, repository

How can I download only a specific folder or directory from a remote Git repo hosted on GitHub?

Say the example GitHub repo lives here:

```
git@github.com:foobar/Test.git
```

Its directory structure:

```
Test/
├── foo/ 
│   ├── a.py
│   └── b.py   
└── bar/
    ├── c.py
    └── d.py
```

I want to download only the **foo** folder and not clone the whole Test project.

Comment: I wrote a shell script for this using svn checkout - https://github.com/Decad/github-downloader

Comment: Can somebody explain to me why there isn't an "official" web-interface solution to this? It seems like a trivial feature to implement, yet super useful.

Comment: I've created an open source project, called [GitHubFolderDownloader](https://github.com/VahidN/GitHubFolderDownloader). It lets you to download a single folder of a repository without cloning or downloading the whole repository.

Comment: see @janos answer svn alternative is the best, no auth, no registration, no limit, no plugins

Comment: @Alexander There is an official way. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70729494/11218031

Comment: +1 for Declan's shell script - it lets you specify just the repo path and you're off to the races. In case people want to hack things further in python, here's a python version of Declan's svn script, updated to work with branches named `main` as well as `master`: [github_downloader.py](https://github.com/dp12/dotfiles/blob/master/python-scripts/github_downloader.py)

Comment: There's an official solution now in git using sparse clone (assuming cloning instead of downloading works for you too). Check the 2022 answer here that works perfectly!  > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/73254328#73254328

Comment: Related: *[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#answer-73254328)*

Comment: FYI, there's a handy web tool that lets you paste a github folder path and it delivers you a downloadable zip. No need to install any 3rd party tools, SVN, or anything like that. https://download-directory.github.io

Answer (score 1752):

**Update Apr. 2021**: there are a few tools created by the community that can do this for you:

- [Download Directory](https://download-directory.github.io/) (Credits to [fregante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288906/fregante))

  - It has also been [integrated](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/pull/951) into the excellent [**Refined Github**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github) chrome extension as a button in the Github web UI.
- [GitZip](http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip) (Credits to [Kino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2238770/kino) - see his answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo/33753575#33753575))
- [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit) (Credits to [Minhas Kamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4684058/minhas-kamal?tab=profile) - see his answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo/38879691#38879691))

Note: if you're trying to download a large number of files, you may need to provide a token to these tools to avoid rate limiting.

---

**Original (manual) approach:** Checking out an individual directory is not supported by `git` natively, but Github can do this via SVN. If you checkout your code with subversion, Github will essentially convert the repo from git to subversion on the backend, then serve up the requested directory.

Here's how you can use this feature to download a specific folder. I'll use the popular javascript library `lodash` as an example.

1. **Navigate to the folder you want to download**. Let's download `/test` from `master` branch.
   [image: github repo URL example]
2. **Modify the URL for subversion**. Replace `tree/master` with `trunk`.

   `https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/master/test` ➜

   `https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test`
3. **Download the folder**. Go to the command line and grab the folder with SVN.

```
svn checkout https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test
```

You might not see any activity immediately because Github takes up to 30 seconds to convert larger repositories, so be patient.

> *Full URL format explanation:*
>
> - If you're interested in `master` branch, use `trunk` instead. So the full path is `trunk/foldername`
> - If you're interested in `foo` branch, use `branches/foo` instead. The
>   full path looks like `branches/foo/foldername`
> - Protip: You can use `svn ls` to see available tags and branches before downloading if you wish

That's all! Github [supports more subversion features](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/) as well, including support for committing and pushing changes.

Comment: I modified this to use `svn export`, as I didn't want a Subversion working copy. Then I added the resulting folder in Git. (I somehow lost a large piece of my directory tree, so I exported from the repo I forked.)

Comment: Would there be a similar solution if the folder is in a branch?

Comment: @num3ric- sorry for the late reply, but you should be able to replace "trunk" with "branches/yourbranch"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With TortoiseSVN, I can easily and visually operate everything without caring about the ```master``` & ```trunk``` problem.

Comment: Does this still work? Tried this with TortiseSVN and I get a permission error, asking me to supply credentials.

Comment: @john Are you sure you are using the correct URL? You shouldn't have to provide credentials to get a "read-only" copy of the repo.

Comment: I'm using TortoiseSVN's `Import` command. I am sure I'm providing the correct URL in a similar format as shown in the answer. I even tried using the visual inspector and selected the required folder (no URL typed) and the result is the same.

Comment: I tried it with Jekyll and get "This repository is hosted on a new server that doesn't support SVN yet. Please contact support if you need SVN access for this repository."

Comment: Why does this work ? Does github explicitly support svn somehow?

Comment: @JamesWierzba yes, GitHub added `svn` support a few years ago. It used to be read-only (you could only do checkouts against a github repo) but they've since added support for a lot of other things, like commits. I've added a couple links to my answer which will probably explain things a lot better.

Comment: If you are using Github 2 factor auth you will need to generate an access code which you can use as a password on the CLI => https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Comment: @technophyle it still does. I think this post is due for an update though so I'll try to make the steps more clear.

Comment: @nick fixed 'branch' to 'branches' in the Full URL format explanation, second bullet. The copy/paste didn't work, so I noticed it :)

Comment: nice. additional example for folks wanting all images "provided" by cv2: svn checkout 
  'https'://github.com/opencv/opencv/trunk/samples/data

Comment: For those without `svn` installed, I used `git svn clone` in place of `svn checkout` and all went well (it does add a .git directory which is easy enough to delete if necessary).

Comment: Thanks this works. It is a shame that github does not provide a simple download button in the web interface. You can only download the entire repo as a zip file...

Comment: `svn checkout https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test` doesn't work in Colab

Comment: and once you have it in local are you able to push changes in the folder?

Comment: @DavidMarciel I believe so, but you would need to commit/push changes with svn, cannot use git. read more here: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/support-for-subversion-clients

Comment: what if it's a private repo?

Comment: @SérgioMichels Is there a way to download the folder in compressed format?

Comment: Still works great as of 2020/6/18 - downloaded a particular folder in a given branch on Windows 10 using TortoiseSVN -> Export feature (available right clicking on any File Explorer directory), Used this URL: `https://github.com/$organization/$repo/branches/$branch/$directory`

Comment: DownGit is plug n play

Comment: As of 28th October 2020, if you attempt the method ```repo/branches/foo_branch/bar_folder``` you will receive a status 410, feature gone.

Comment: Is there a way to use svn checkout for git repository using ssh ??

Comment: `svn export https://github.com/$organization/$repo/branches/$branch/$directory` worked fine with `svn --version` `1.10.3 (r1842928)` and [URL](https://github.com/docker-library/php/branches/master/7.4/bullseye/cli) now

Comment: @Hugo there's a better way which doesn't need any extra tool. Posted it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70729494/11218031

Comment: One may also download specific tags inthe same manner as branches, by replacing branches with tags, e.g. svn checkout https://github.com/ex/ex/tags/foo/pathtofolder

Comment: works also with tags `svn checkout https://github.com/<organization>/<repository>/tags/<tag_name>/folder`

Comment: This method does not work with git lfs.

Comment: GitHub is ending support of SVN on **January 8, 2024** https://github.blog/2023-01-20-sunsetting-subversion-support/

Comment: mfw when I see this comment while trying to use svn to grab something on the 17th of January 2024 ‍♂️

Comment: The suggested edit is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428003/2029983) (ref @NareshBisht )

Answer (score 1141):

## Go to [**DownGit**](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit) > Enter Your URL > Download!

You can **DIRECTLY DOWNLOAD** or create **DOWNLOAD LINK** for any GitHub public directory or file from [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit)-

---

[image: DownGit]

---

You may also configure properties of the downloaded file- [detailed usage](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit/blob/master/README.md#advanced-usage).

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I fell into the same problem as the question-asker and could not find any simple solution. So, I developed this tool for my own use first, then opened it for everyone :)</sub>

Comment: The base method is-
1. take the directory link (used [angular-route](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js)),
2. go to [GitHub API](https://api.github.com),
3. search through the directory and download all files,
4. create a zip file with it (I have used [jszip](https://cdn.rawgit.com,/Stuk/jszip/v3.0.0/dist/jszip.min.js)) & save it as file (used [filesaver](https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js) for this).

For clear understanding I would suggest to take a look in [my project](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit).

Comment: @MYounas Sorry I cannot suggest you any tutorial as I did not follow any. You may get some help from [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Comment: This is cool but it doesn't work with automated tools (like wget)

Comment: Thanks for creating this,  but it does not work for me:
Trying to download a directory from MSDN code samples.
Git url is https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft.git
Directory is: msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/Official Windows Platform Sample/XAML SwapChainPanel DirectX interop sample/
URL from downgit is:
https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/Official Windows Platform Sample/XAML SwapChainPanel DirectX interop sample/
I then tried wget "above URL&fileName=swapPanel.zip&rootDirectory=true"
just created index.html in directory, no download

Comment: Also tried download directly on downgit webpage, but got a 404 error

Comment: @Paulus https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/Official is not a valid URL. Please check.

Comment: Hi Minas, I just copied the link address of the first URL in my comment, pasted it into chrome, and came out at the github page. Should I maybe leave off the .git suffix?
maybe spaces in Microsoft's directory names are causing a problem?

Comment: @Paulus I see the repo is too big, it far surpasses 500 file limit. You can download a sub-folder though: [link](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmicrosoftarchive%2Fmsdn-code-gallery-microsoft%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2FOfficial%20Windows%20Driver%20Kit%20Sample%2FWindows%20Driver%20Kit%20(WDK)%208.1%20Samples%2F%5BC%2B%2B%5D-windows-driver-kit-81-cpp%2FWDK%208.1%20C%2B%2B%20Samples%2FAC97%20Driver%20Sample%2FC%2B%2B%2FINFViewer%2FHTML)

Comment: Not working on link https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/tree/master/03%20-%20Your%20First%20Application/PartyInvites

Comment: @Woland I was able to successfully download the directory you shared. Please check if you have any script blocker or access right issues.

Comment: before doing this make sure your repository is public , if it is private then goto settings and first make it public repository.

Comment: DownGit was exactly what I needed: To download a specific folder from a repo without creating a new git directory in order to do so (like the subversion method requires). Thanks very much for making this.

Comment: Not work for https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/release/6.0/src/SignalR

Comment: @zwcloud this is too big a directory, so GitHub (and not DownGit) does not allow to download it.

Comment: I got stuck at 219 files when downloading sample code from asp.net core.
Download Directory did it for me 1.6k files

Comment: This is my preferred solution as it doesn't requiring downloading or using additional software.

Comment: The website got blacklisted by my antivirus...

Comment: @VascoCansadoCarvalho This is because of my association with keylogger/virus development :(  
DownGit is totally safe though

Answer (score 691):

### Two options for this feature:

#### Option 1: GitZip Browser Extension

> [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gitzip-for-github/ffabmkklhbepgcgfonabamgnfafbdlkn), [Edge Extension](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/gitzip-for-github/nlgkiabjnbdndgblhcaobimbpifcdkjj), [Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gitzip/)

Usage:

1. Browse any Github repository page.
2. Two ways to download:

   1. Choose the items:

      1. In default, you can double click on items or check the checkbox on the front of items.
      2. Click download button at the bottom-right of the page.
   2. In context menu:

      1. Click "GitZip Download" >  "Whole Repository" or "Current Folder".
      2. Move the mouse cursor on the item and click "GitZip Download" > "Selected Folder/File".
      3. Click "GitZip Download" >  "Checked Items" after doing 2-1-1.
3. See the progress dashboard and wait for browser trigger download.
4. Get the ZIP file.

Get Token:

1. Click GitZip Extension icon on your browser.
2. Click "Normal" or "Private" link besides "Get Token".
3. Authorize GitZip permission on Github auth page.
4. Back to repo page of the beginning.
5. Continue to use.

---

#### Option 2: Github gh-page

> http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip by using GitHub API, and JSZip, FileSaver.js libraries.

Step1: Input github url to the field at the top-right.
Step2: Press enter or click download for download zip directly or click search for view the list of sub-folders and files.
Step3: Click "Download Zip File" or "Get File" button to get files.

In most cases, it works fine, except that the folder contains more than 1,000 files, because of the Github Trees API limitation. (refers to [Github API#Contents](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents))

And it also can support private/public repos and upgrade the rate limit, if you have GitHub account and use "get token" link in this site.

Comment: @MYounas How you want to use it? Do you mean create a download link with any repo directory path, like "http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/?repo=download/repo/path" ?

Comment: Nop,man i want any helpfull link through which i am able to learn how i can make this type of service like you did "gitzip".

Comment: @MYounas See about OAuth, Trees, Blobs chapters in [Github API Doc.](https://developer.github.com/v3/), and also use JSZip, FileSaver.js js libraries for gitzip implementation.

Comment: currently broken ?

Comment: @RayHulha Hi, What's it shows? What's your browser? safari, chrome or others? Maybe you can make a new issue on [github repo](https://github.com/KinoLien/gitzip/issues).

Comment: I tried to get https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java/tree/master/flexmark/src/main/java with current chrome on win 10 and it just hung.

Comment: Would anyone b interested in a chrome extension that does this?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the GitHub authorization request in your service, but as I interpret it, I would be granting you a read and write access to my account. Is that correct?

Comment: @mr5 Basically yes, but this point was a dilemma to me, and also to others (refers: [jollygoodcode issues](https://github.com/jollygoodcode/jollygoodcode.github.io/issues/6)). We cannot get a read-only permission for your repositories.

Comment: @goldylucks I did this, see the new answer.

Comment: @stackdave Sorry, i don't get it. Do you mean it is not private in the process of get a token?

Comment: best for me was svn, no auth needed,  these programs need Auth

Comment: No Firefox version?

Comment: @AaronFranke Now available, try it!

Comment: @xamDev Could you tell me the url?

Comment: @xamDev I tried but it works well. (environment: Chrome: 65.0.3325.162, gitzip: 0.2.1) And have you try in the gh-page? also empty zip?

Comment: definitely not working; as of this post's date, the spin symbol in the download button gives the impression to be doing something,  but nothing actually happens :-(

Comment: @Kino Is there a way to download fx. https://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/?download=KinoLien/gitzip without using a browser? Fx curl or python?

Comment: @Paw I don't have the plan currently. Maybe you can use SVN or [Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925766/2238770) instead.

Comment: Instruction (Usage #2) apparently (at least in Chrome?) should say "right click" not double click, on a blank space on the repo page of the items you need. Then step 3 is just to click on the "download as zip" option that comes up in the right click menu. Once I figured out for myself how to use the extension this was a great solution.

Comment: @JoshSutterfield I installed the extension on chrome but right click on blank space of github not showing download as zip option. Is your extension still working?

Answer (score 197):

If you have `svn`, you can use `svn export` to do this:

```
svn export https://github.com/foobar/Test.git/trunk/foo
```

Notice the URL format:

- The base URL is `https://github.com/`
- `/trunk` appended at the end

Before you run `svn export`, it's good to first verify the content of the directory with:

```
svn ls https://github.com/foobar/Test.git/trunk/foo
```

Comment: Does this still work? Tried this with TortiseSVN and I get a permission error, asking me to supply credentials.

Comment: @john I'm sure this is too late to be of much help, but do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your GitHub account? If so, I *think* I read somewhere you'll have to use a pre-generated key for the password (which you'll need to find in the GitHub settings).

Comment: Regarding the URL formatting, you can keep the `.git` extension. You can use the full project link, and start by using `svn ls` followed by the project full path. Example: `svn ls https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino.git`. To export just one folder, you just add the `/trunk` followed by the desired path, like `svn export https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino.git/trunk/libraries/DHTlib`. It is easier to keep the project path intact.

Comment: @jgrocha I'm not sure it worked that way back in 2013, but it does now, so thanks, updated the post

Comment: An example: to download the content in `https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/tree/master/examples/wsgi`, run `svn export https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio.git/trunk/examples/wsgi`. A directory called `wsgi` will be created under the current working directory. Only source files, nothing else. No `.git`, no subversion related files.

Comment: Best alternative for me

Comment: `git svn clone https://github.com/Qamar4P/LolAdapter.git/trunk/lol-adapter -r HEAD` Nice alternative ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/37735157/5710872

Comment: Sadly, this will no longer work since Github shut down their Subversion server in early 2024.

Answer (score 99):

#### For a Generic git Repo:

If you want to download files, not clone the repository with history, you can do this with **`git-archive`**.

**`git-archive`** makes a compressed zip or tar archive of a git repository. Some things that make it special:

1. **You can choose which files or directories in the git repository to archive.**
2. It doesn't archive the `.git/` folder, or any untracked files in the repository it's run on.
3. You can archive a specific branch, tag, or commit. Projects managed with git often use this to generate archives of versions of the project (beta, release, 2.0, etc.) for users to download.

An example of creating an archive of the `docs/usage` directory from a remote repo you're connected to with ssh:

```
# in terminal
$ git archive --format tar --remote ssh://server.org/path/to/git HEAD docs/usage > /tmp/usage_docs.tar
```

More information in [this blog post](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/09/git-tip-of-week-git-archive.html) and the [git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html).

#### Note on GitHub Repos:

[GitHub doesn't allow `git-archive` access](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/322818593748303873). ☹️

Comment: `git archive --format tar` format is not tar.gz, but tar.

Comment: This should be the best answer

Comment: I think this is the best answer but keep note that git archive command doesn't work with https protocol.

Comment: @yukihane edited extension from tar.gz to tar, hopefully OP is onboard with this

Comment: It is possible to do `| tar -x` to skip the creation of a tar file.

Answer (score 88):

After trying all the answers, the best solution for me was:

#### GitHub's Visual Studio Code-based editor.

Pros:

1. doesn't require any extra tool like [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) or API tokens.
2. No limit on size of content
3. Saves as a directory or file, and not archive.

#### Instructions

1. Go to any repository. (example: https://github.com/RespiraWorks/Ventilator/tree/master/software)
2. Press <kbd>.</kbd> or replace `.com` with `.dev` in the URL to open the repository in GitHub's internal editor
3. In the *Explorer* pane (left side or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), right-click on the required file/folder and select *Download*.
4. In the *Select Folder* dialog box, choose the directory on your disk under which you want the selected file/folder to exist.

#### Note

I tried other solutions like in accepted answer but,

1. I don't want to install and learn SVN only for this.
2. Other tools like [Download Directory](https://download-directory.github.io/), [Refined GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github), [GitZip](http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip), [DownGit](https://downgit.github.io/) either require API tokens or cannot download large directories.

#### Other options

- Visual Studio Code with [Remote Repositories](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.remotehub) extension to open the repository and download the file/folder.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for directories (anymore?). Microsoft seems to have nerfed this to only 'upload' to directories and only download files.

Comment: @i30817 Verified just now that it works. When you download a folder(A), it asks you to choose a local folder(B). Then, it creates A under B while showing the progress at the status bar of code editor.

Is anything different for you ?

Comment: Yes. If you select a folder, only 'upload' appears. To select multiple files and download is possible, though, you'll have multiple downloads appear, one per file.

Comment: @i30817 I found the reason. On checking code, it appears that this feature uses an API(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker) which is only available in chrome/edge/chromium 86+ and opera. If you're using something else, you may not be able to download the folders.

Comment: That figures, i was using firefox. Oh well, i no longer need it since my specific case had another solution.

Comment: It still works as of Mar 7, 2022. I like this approach because when you put a link to another server that makes you a zip file that server has the potential to append malicious stuff.

Comment: Works like charm in Aug 2022

Comment: @AvinashThakur, **What browser requirements?** tho

Comment: @Pacerier only Chrome or Chromium based(Edge, Opera, etc.). not firefox, safari, etc.

Comment: Knew this thing already but did forgot when neccessary. Thanks for the post bro

Comment: I love it because it doesn't require additional tools or workarounds though in my case downloading a huge directory with ~3000 png files cloning the repo locally and then `cp`ing the desired folder was much much quicker 

Answer (score 39):

### `git clone --filter` downloads only the required folders

E.g., to clone only objects required for subdirectory `small/` of this repository: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-partial-clone-big-small notably ignoring subdirectory `big/` which contains large files, I can do:

```
git clone -n --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 \
  https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-partial-clone-big-small
cd test-git-partial-clone-big-small
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone small
git checkout
```

The `--filter` option was added together with an update to the remote protocol, and it truly prevents objects from being downloaded from the server.

I have covered this in more detail at: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934)

Tested on git 2.30.0 on January 2021.

Comment: @VonC I think I beat you to it this once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-sparsely-checkout-only-one-single-file-from-a-git-repository/52270527#comment91530496_52270527 and I only looked at it after the release XD! I was of course Googling today a bit after 2.22 release, all answer have already been updated of course ;-) It never ceases to amuse me how there is always another semi duplicate left, always, and I end up finding it one year later with a slightly different query. I don't intend to beat you on git though, too hard, but keep an eye on necromancer counts! haha

Comment: @VonC joking of course, I upvote your stuff as well obviously. I just need to find a way to redeem those points into money now XD

Comment: this takes ages. It fetches each file in d1, individually.

Comment: @TheFool I get similar times in both on my test repos, let me know if you have a precise test repo + commands.

Comment: I tried getting one folder of this repo, each one contains 1000+ files. https://github.com/yannh/kubernetes-json-schema/tree/master/master-standalone-strict. When I simply clone the entire repo, it is much quicker than getting one folder with the describe method here.

Comment: @TheFool OK I reproduced, thanks. This answer contained an outdated command `git checkout`, my main answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934 had the correct one `git sparse-checkout set`. With that it's instantaneous. Updated.

Comment: Amazing! This works without using any other website or using svn which github ended support for. But this method seems kinda intuitive and well I learned something new today. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

Nothing wrong with other answers but I just thought I'd share step-by-step instructions for those wandering through this process for the first time.

### How to download a single folder from a github repository (Mac OS X):

> ~ To open Terminal just click spotlight and type terminal then hit enter

1. On a Mac you likely already have SVN (to test just open terminal and
   type **"svn"** or **"which svn"** ~ without the quote marks)
2. On Github: Locate the Github path to your git folder (not the repo) by clicking the specific folder name within a repo
3. Copy the path from the address bar of the browser
4. **Open Terminal** and type: **svn export**
5. Next paste in the address (eg.):
   **https://github.com/mingsai/Sample-Code/tree/master/HeadsUpUI**
6. Replace the words: **tree/master**
7. with the word: **trunk**
8. Type in the destination folder for the files (in this example, I
   store the target folder inside of the Downloads folder for the
   current user)
9. Here space is just the spacebar not the word **(space) ~/Downloads/HeadsUpUI**
10. The final terminal command shows the full command to download the
     folder (compare the address to step 5) **svn export
     https://github.com/mingsai/Sample-Code/trunk/HeadsUpUI
     ~/Downloads/HeadsUpUI**

BTW - If you are on Windows or some other platform you can find a binary download of subversion (svn) at http://subversion.apache.org

> ~ If you want to checkout the folder rather than simply download it try using the svn help (tldr: replace **export** with **checkout**)

**Update**

Regarding the comment on resuming an interrupted download/checkout. I would try running `svn cleanup` followed by `svn update`. Please search SO for additional options.

Comment: I have to download many files from a specific folder and got this error in the middle of the download:

svn: E175002: REPORT of '/bgmartins/scripts-parlamento/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (https://github.com)

Do you how can I resume the download?

Comment: Worked for me. That's amazing.

Comment: Amazing! Worked great!

Answer (score 31):

Whoever is working on specific folder he needs to clone that particular folder itself, to do so please follow below steps by using sparse checkout.

1. Create a directory.
2. Initialize a Git repository. (`git init`)
3. Enable Sparse Checkouts. (`git config core.sparsecheckout true`)
4. Tell Git which directories you want (echo 2015/brand/May( refer to folder you want to work on) >> `.git/info/sparse-checkout`)
5. Add the remote (`git remote add -f origin https://jafartke.com/mkt-imdev/DVM.git`)
6. Fetch the files (`git pull origin master` )

Comment: Too bad this comment did not get enough upvotes. Looks like the solution provided applies to all git repositories and not just the github one.

Comment: This doesn't actually do what was desired, though. It still clones the whole repository, it just doesn't check out some folders.

Comment: Resolved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository

Comment: I get this error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory.

Answer (score 25):

You cannot; unlike Subversion, where each subdirectory can be checked out individually, Git operates on a whole-repository basis.

For projects where finer-grained access is necessary, you can use submodules -- each submodule is a separate Git project, and thus can be cloned individually.

It is conceivable that a Git front-end (e.g. GitHub's web interface, or gitweb) could choose to provide an interface for you to extract a given folder, but to my knowledge none of them do that (though they do let you download individual files, so if the folder does not contain too many files, that is an option)

**Edit** - GitHub actually offers access via SVN, which would allow you to do just this (as per comment). See https://github.com/blog/1438-improved-svn-here-to-stay-old-svn-going-away for latest instructions on how to do this

Comment: is there any thing via github API?

Answer (score 23):

### 2019 Summary

There are a variety of ways to handle this, depending on whether or not you want to do this manually or programmatically.

There are four options summarized below. And for those that prefer a more hands-on explanation, I've put together a YouTube video: [Download Individual Files and Folders from GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HRvE_Oa_aM).

Also, I've posted a [similar answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098402/4500152) for those that need to download single files from GitHub (as opposed to folders).

---

**1. GitHub User Interface**

- There's a download button on the repository's homepage. Of course, this downloads the entire repo, after which you would need to unzip the download and then manually drag out the specific folder you need.

**2. Third Party Tools**

- There are a variety of browser extensions and web apps that can handle this, with [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/) being one of them. Simply paste in the GitHub URL to the folder (e.g. `https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/tree/master/lib`) and press the "Download" button.

**3. Subversion**

- GitHub does not support git-archive (the git feature that would allow us to download specific folders). GitHub does however, support a variety of Subversion features, one of which we can use for this purpose. Subversion is a version control system (an alternative to git). You'll need Subversion installed. Grab the GitHub URL for the folder you want to download. You'll need to modify this URL, though. You want the link to the repository, followed by the word "trunk", and ending with the path to the nested folder. In other words, using the same folder link example that I mentioned above, we would replace "tree/master" with "trunk". Finally, open up a terminal, navigate to the directory that you want the content to get downloaded to, type in the following command (replacing the URL with the URL you constructed): `svn export https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/trunk/lib`, and press enter.

**4. GitHub API**

- This is the solution you'll need if you want to accomplish this task programmatically. And this is actually what DownGit is using under the hood. Using [GitHub's REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), write a script that does a GET request to the content endpoint. The endpoint can be constructed as follows: `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`. After replacing the placeholders, an example endpoint is: `https://api.github.com/repos/babel/babel-eslint/contents/lib`. This gives you JSON data for all of the content that exists in that folder. The data has everything you need, including whether or not the content is a folder or file, a download URL if it's a file, and an API endpoint if it's a folder (so that you can get the data for that folder). Using this data, the script can recursively go through all content in the target folder, create folders for nested folders, and download all of the files for each folder. Check out [DownGit's code](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit/blob/master/app/home/down-git.js) for inspiration.

Comment: I built an easy to use wrapper around the github api. all you have to do is add `ss` in front of the url while browsing through the repo on github. explained it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77459783/11565176

Answer (score 18):

If you truly just want to just **"download"** the folder and not **"clone"** it (for development), the easiest way to simply get a *copy* of the most recent version of the repository (and therefore a folder/file within it), without needing to clone the whole repo or even install git in the first place, is to download a zip archive (for any repo, fork, branch, commit, etc.) by going to the desired repository/fork/branch/commit on GitHub (e.g. `http(s)://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commit/<Sha1>` for a copy of the files as they were after a specific commit) and selecting the `Downloads` button near the upper-right.

This archive format contains none of the git-repo magic, just the tracked files themselves (and perhaps a few .gitignore files if they were tracked, but you can ignore those :p) - that means that if the code changes and you want to stay on top, you'll have to manually re-download it, and it also means you won't be able to use it as a git repository...

Not sure if that's what you're looking for in this case (again, "download"/view vs "clone"/develop), but it can be useful nonetheless...

Comment: If you don't see a download link, make sure you're on a main repo page (not a child directory.) Seems like you can only download a zip of the entire repo. Also, [this github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) might be useful.

Comment: Easy point-and-click access. Easy to get a prior release. Easy to pull the desired folder out of the downloaded zip. Thank you.

Comment: The generic URL to get download from in `tar.gz`: `https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}/archive/${hash}.tar.gz`

Answer (score 16):

#### Just add `ss` to the start of the GitHub URL: (*github.com -> [ssgithub.com](https://ssgithub.com)*)

I built this simple webpage that does this for you, so just:

1. Navigate to the directory/file you want to download on GitHub
2. Add `ss` to the start of the URL in the address bar

Clicking on *Download* should zip just the contents of that directory and download them to your device.

[[Demo video](https://youtu.be/ntPzucAbggQ)]

Comment: Cool! No webapps or magic needed!

Answer (score 14):

There's a Python3 pip package called `githubdl` that can do this*:

```
export GIT_TOKEN=1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
pip install githubdl
githubdl -u http://github.com/foobar/test -d foo
```

The project page is [here](http://githubdl.seso.io/)

* Disclaimer: I wrote this package.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this package, I have been helpful in the COLAB Environment

Comment: You got my $1. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you are comfortable with Unix commands, you don't need special dependencies or web applications for this. You can download the repository as a tarball and untar only what you need.

Example (woff2 files from a subdirectory in [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome)):

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tarball | tar xz --wildcards "*/web-fonts-with-css/webfonts/*.woff2" --strip-components=3
```

- More about the link format: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link (including how to get a ZIP file or specific branches/refs)
- Keep the initial part of the path (`*/`) to match any directory. GitHub creates a wrapper directory with the commit ref in the name, so it can't be known.
- You probably want `--strip-components` to be the same as the amount of slashes (`/`) in the path (previous argument).

This will download the whole tarball. Use the SVN method mentioned in the other answers if this has to be avoided or if you want to be nice to the GitHub servers.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I do it with [Git v2.25.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.25.0.txt), and it was also tested with v2.26.2. This trick doesn't work with v2.30.1.

#### TLDR

```
git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv

# Requires Git 2.25.x to 2.26.2
git sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
```

You can use [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) to avoid installing a specific version of Git:

```
git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv

# Requires Git 2.25.x to 2.26.2
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/:/code/ --workdir=/code/ alpine/git:v2.26.2 sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
```

### Full solution

```
# Bare minimum clone of OpenCV
git clone --no-checkout --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/opencv/
```

Output:

```
opencv
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (529/529), done.

# Downloaded only ~7.3MB , takes ~3 seconds
# du = disk usage, -s = summary, -h = human-readable
```

And:

```
du -sh opencv
```

Output:

```
7.3M    opencv/
```

And:

```
# Set target directory
cd opencv
git sparse-checkout set data/haarcascades
```

Output:

```
...
Updating files: 100% (17/17), done.
# Takes ~10 seconds, depending on your specifications
```

And:

```
# View downloaded files
du -sh data/haarcascades/
```

Output:

```
9.4M    data/haarcascades/
```

And:

```
ls data/haarcascades/
```

Output:

```
haarcascade_eye.xml                      haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml      haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml  haarcascade_smile.xml
haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml      haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml  haarcascade_lowerbody.xml                   haarcascade_upperbody.xml
haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml           haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml   haarcascade_profileface.xml
haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml  haarcascade_fullbody.xml              haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml          haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml       haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml
```

### References

- [git-sparse-checkout-blog](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#sparse-checkout-and-partial-clones)
- [git-sparse-checkout-docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)
- [git-filter-props-docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

Comment: Why doesn't it work with `v2.30.1`?

Comment: In my quick test just now on `2.38.1`, I just had to do a `git checkout main` after running `git sparse-checkout set foo`, and it seemed to only pull down the single folder that I had specified.

Answer (score 10):

You can use *git-svn* in the following way.

First, replace `tree/master` with `trunk`.
Then, install `git-svn` by `sudo apt install git-svn`.

```
git svn clone https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/test
```

This way, you don't have to go through the pain of setting SVN, specifically for Windows users.

Comment: Thank You. I can vouch that it works for Windows. Doesn't work on gcloud though. It says git: 'svn' is not a command

Comment: `sudo apt install git-svn`is required when running through WSL.

Answer (score 9):

You can do a simple download of the directory tree:

```
git archive --remote git@github.com:foobar/Test.git HEAD:foo | tar xf -
```

But if you mean to check it out, and be able to do commits and push them back, no you can't do that.

Comment: Invalid command: 'git-upload-archive 'foobar/Test.git''
  You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
  Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
  GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: @g_inherit I can reproduce this issue. Although this might be the right direction, this answer is invalid.

Comment: despite so many down votes this is the only advice that worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Another specific example:

Like I want to download 'iOS Pro Geo' folder from the url

https://github.com/alokc83/APRESS-Books-Source-Code-/**tree/master**/%20Pro%20iOS%20Geo

and I can do so via

```
svn checkout https://github.com/alokc83/APRESS-Books-Source-Code-/trunk/%20Pro%20iOS%20Geo
```

Note **trunk** in the path

**Edited: (as per Tommie C's comment)**

Yes, using **export**  instead of **checkout** would give a clean copy without extra git repository files.

```
svn export https://github.com/alokc83/APRESS-Books-Source-Code-/trunk/%20Pro%20iOS%20Geo
```

**Edited:** If tree/master is not there in url then Fork it and it will be there in Forked url.

Comment: Just need to change checkout to export if you just want to download a copy of the folder rather than checkout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can we dive a branch ? let's say I want to download feature1 branch's aaa folder

Answer (score 9):

### `git sparse-checkout`

> [Git 2.25.0](https://github.blog/2020-01-13-highlights-from-git-2-25/) includes a new experimental `git sparse-checkout` command that makes the existing feature easier to use, along with some important performance benefits for large repositories. ([The GitHub Blog](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/))

Example with [current version](https://github.blog/2020-03-22-highlights-from-git-2-26/#updates-to-git-sparse-checkout):

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse https://github.com/git/git.git
cd git
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout add t
```

#### Most notably

- [`--sparse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---sparse) checks out only top-level directory files of `git` repository into working copy
- `git sparse-checkout add t` incrementally adds/checks out `t` subfolder of `git`

#### Other elements

- [`git sparse-checkout init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt-eminitem) does some preparations to enable partial checkouts
- `--filter=blob:none` optimizes data fetching by downloading  only necessary git objects (take a look at [partial clone feature](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#sparse-checkout-and-partial-clones) for further infos)
- [`--cone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout#_cone_pattern_set) also speeds up performance by applying more restricted file inclusion patterns

---

#### GitHub status

> GitHub is still evaluating this feature internally while it’s enabled on a select few repositories [...]. As the feature stabilizes and matures, we’ll keep you updated with its progress. ([docs](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#one))

Comment: `git sparse checkout` is not strictly needed, at least not anymore. `git checkout` alone also only obtains the missing blobs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504849/895245

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers helped in my situation. If you are developing for Windows, you likely don't have svn. In many situations one can't count on users to have Git installed either, or don't want to download entire repositories for other reasons. Some of the people that answered this question, such as Willem van Ketwich and aztack, made tools to accomplish this task. However, if the tool isn't written for the language you are using, or you don't want to install a third party library, these don't work.

However, there is a much easier way. GitHub has an API that allows you to download a single file or an entire directory's contents [using GET requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/). You can access a directory using `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo_name/contents/:path` that returns a JSON object enumerating all the files in the directory. Included in the enumeration is a link to the raw content of the file, the `download_url` parameter. The file can then be downloaded using that URL.

It's a two step process that requires the ability to make GET requests, but this can be implemented in pretty much any language, on any platform. It can be used to get files or directories.

Comment: This works only for single files. The OP is asking for a way to download a folder and the `download_url` for folders is `null`. Please, read the question carefuly, before posting an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ghget](https://github.com/mohd-akram/ghget) with any URL copied from the address bar:

```
ghget https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/airline-safety
```

It's a self-contained portable shell script that doesn't use SVN (which didn't work for me on a big repo). It also doesn't use the API so it doesn't require a token and isn't rate-limited.

Disclaimer: I made it.

Answer (score 6):

Just to amplify previous answers, a real example from a real GitHub repository to a local directory would be:

```
svn ls https://github.com/rdcarp/playing-cards/trunk/PumpkinSoup.PlayingCards.Interfaces

svn export https://github.com/rdcarp/playing-cards/trunk/PumpkinSoup.PlayingCards.Interfaces  /temp/SvnExport/Washburn
```

Sometimes a concrete example helps clarify the substitutions proposed.

Answer (score 6):

For whatever reason, the `svn` solution does not work for me, and since I have no need of `svn` for anything else, it did not make sense to spend time trying to make it, so I looked for a simple solution using tools I already had.  This script uses only `curl` and `awk` to download all files in a GitHub directory described as `"/:user:repo/contents/:path"`.

The returned body of a call to the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content)
`"GET /repos/:user:repo/contents/:path"` command returns an object that includes a `"download_url"` link for each file in a directory.

This command-line script calls that REST API using `curl` and sends the result through AWK, which filters out all but the "download_url" lines, erases quote marks and commas from the links, and then downloads the links using another call to curl.

```bash
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/contents/:path | awk \
     '/download_url/ { gsub("\"|,", "", $2); system("curl -O " $2); }'
```

Comment: I get `awk: cmd. line:1: /download_url/ { gsub("\"|,", "", $2); system("curl -O "$2"); }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                           ^ syntax error`

Comment: Batch equivalent of this command: `FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=4 %%a IN ('curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/contents/:path 2^>NUL ^| findstr "download_url"') DO curl -O "%%~a"`

Comment: My favourite solution, thanks to `curl` and `awk`. if only it could recurse.

Answer (score 6):

## Just 5 steps to go

- Download **SVN** from [here](https://sliksvn.com/download/).
- Open **CMD** and go to **SVN bin directory** like:
  `cd %ProgramFiles%\SlikSvn\bin`
- Let's suppose I wan to download this **directory URL**
  `https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/develop/src/Samples`
- Replace
  `tree/develop`
  or `tree/master` with `trunk`
- Now fire this last command to download folder in same directory.

```
svn export https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/trunk/src/Samples
```

Answer (score 5):

It's one of the few places where SVN is better than Git.

In the end we've gravitated towards three options:

1. Use wget to grab the data from GitHub (using the raw file view).
2. Have upstream projects publish the required data subset as build artifacts.
3. Give up and use the full checkout. It's big hit on the first build, but unless you get lot of traffic, it's not too much hassle in the following builds.

Comment: Well, it's less Git vs Subversion and more that GitHub flat-out doesn't allow git-archive. (I'd love to know why.)

Answer (score 5):

I use Linux so, put this in *[~/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*, called even :D *$HOME/.bashrc*

```
git-dowloadfolder(){
a="$1"
svn checkout ${a/tree\/master/trunk}

}
```

Then refresh the shell with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then use it with git-downloadfolder blablabla :D

Answer (score 4):

To export a directory from GitHub, replace "/tree/master/" in the directory's url with "/trunk/".

For example, to export the directory from the following URL:

```
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/sample-hibernate-portlet
```

run the following command:

```
svn export https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/trunk/portlets/sample-hibernate-portlet
```

Answer (score 4):

I have created a simple application that supports download directories, files, and repositories (Private/Public).

Application: https://downdir.vercel.app/

GitHub: https://github.com/renomureza/downdir

Answer (score 3):

Our team wrote a bash script to do this because we didn't want to have to install SVN on our bare bones server.

https://github.com/ojbc/docker/blob/master/java8-karaf3/files/git-download.sh

It uses the github API and can be run from the command line like this:

```
git-download.sh https://api.github.com/repos/ojbc/main/contents/shared/ojb-certs
```

Answer (score 3):

I work with CentOS 7 servers on which I don't have root access, nor git, svn, etc (nor want to!) so made a python script to download any github folder: https://github.com/andrrrl/github-folder-downloader

Usage is simple, just copy the relevant part from a github project, let's say the project is https://github.com/MaxCDN/php-maxcdn/, and you want a folder where some source files are only, then you need to do something like:

`$ python gdownload.py "/MaxCDN/php-maxcdn/tree/master/src" /my/target/dir/`
(will create target folder if doesn't exist)

It requires [lxml](http://lxml.de) library, can be installed with `easy_install lxml`
If you don't have root access (like me) you can create a `.pydistutils.py` file into your `$HOME` dir with these contents:

`[install]
user=1`

And `easy_install lxml` will just work (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33464597/591257).

Answer (score 3):

Open the repository to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) by replacing GitHub with githubbox in the URL, and in CodeSandbox, go to menu *File* and Export it as a [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file.

For the following repository:
https://github.com/geist-org/react/tree/master/examples/custom-themes

Enter the following URL:
https://**githubbox**.com/geist-org/react/tree/master/examples/custom-themes

In CodeSandbox, go to menu *File* and Export it as a ZIP file.

Answer (score 3):

Try it.

https://github.com/twfb/git-directory-download

```
usage: gitd [-h] [-u URL] [-r] [-p] [--proxy PROXY]

Optional arguments:
  -h, --help         Show this help message and exit
  -u URL, --url URL  GitHub URL, split by ",", example: "https://x, http://y"
  -r, --raw          Download from a raw URL
  -p, --parse        Download by parsing HTML
  --proxy PROXY      Proxy configuration. Example: "socks5://127.0.0.1:7891"
```

Example:

1. download by a raw URL: gitd -u "https://github.com/twfb/git-directory-download"
2. download by a raw URL: gitd -r -u "https://github.com/twfb/git-directory-download"
3. download by parsing: gitd -p -u "https://github.com/twfb/git-directory-download"
4. download by raw URL with a proxy: gitd -r -u "https://github.com/twfb/git-directory-download" --proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:7891"

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward answer to this is to first install [TortoiseSVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) using [the download page](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).

During installation, turn on the CLI option, so that it can be used from a command line interface.

Copy the GitHub subdirectory link.

> Example
>
> https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab

Replace *tree/master* with *trunk*,

> https://github.com/tensorflow/models/trunk/research/deeplab

And do

```
svn checkout https://github.com/tensorflow/models/trunk/research/deeplab
```

Files will be downloaded to the *deeplab* folder in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

To be unique, I must say you can also download GitHub folders without [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), Git, or any API.

GitHub supports *raw* links, which you can exploit to download only those files and folders which you need.

I noticed many things. Below is my research collection:

### Mechanism

- Crawl all hyperlinks `<a>` from webpage and get its `href="value"` values
- if an *href* value contains */tree/master/* or */tree/main/* then it is folder link:
  `https://github.com/graysuit/GithubFolderDownloader  /tree/main/  GithubFolderDownloader`
- else if the href value contains */blob/master/* or */blob/main/* then it is a file link:
  `https://github.com/graysuit/GithubFolderDownloader  /blob/main/  GithubFolderDownloader.sln`
- Afterwards, replace *github.com* with *raw.githubusercontent.com* and *remove* */blob/* from the file:
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graysuit/GithubFolderDownloader/main/GithubFolderDownloader.sln`
- It would become a *raw* link. Now you can download it.

### Tool

On the basis of above research, I created a minimalist tool in C# that can grab folders. [graysuit/GithubFolderDownloader](https://github.com/graysuit/GithubFolderDownloader)

**Note:** I am author. You can comment if any thing missing or unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found was [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#answer-73254328)

I added `-b <branch> --single-branch` to the git clone command to download a specific branch. So the command I used was:

```
git clone --depth 1 --single-branch -b <branch> --filter=blob:none --sparse <url>
git sparse-checkout set <directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it programatically and you don't want to rely on SVN, you can use GitHub API to download all the contents recursively.

For inspiration, here's my ruby gist: https://gist.github.com/cvengros/b2a7e82f66519d423b6f

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. The first argument is the URL to the folder, and the second is the place the folder will be downloaded to:

```
function github-dir() {
    svn export "$(sed 's/tree\/master/trunk/' <<< "$1")" "$2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [fetcher](https://github.com/Gyumeijie/github-files-fetcher).

First, install fetcher with the following command:

```
npm install -g github-files-fetcher
```

Then you can download file or folder with its URL:

```
fetcher --url=resource_url  --out=output_directory
```

For example:

```
etcher --url="https://github.com/Gyumeijie/github-files-fetcher/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md" --out=/tmp
```

Comment: This is unspecific. Could you please expand your answer with requirements and an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the gitzip extension for Google Chrome. It’s super easy to use and has helped me download many folders before too!

Answer (score 1):

Download the Git repository folder to a current directory and delete Git files.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

function download_git_folder() {
  repo_url=$1
  branch=$2
  repo_subfolder_path=$3

  repo_folder=$(basename $repo_url)
  git init
  git remote add -f origin ${repo_url}
  git config core.sparseCheckout true
  echo "${repo_subfolder_path}" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
  git pull origin ${branch}
  mv "${repo_subfolder_path}"/* ./

  readarray -td/ root_subfolder <<<"${repo_subfolder_path}"; declare -p root_subfolder;
  rm -rf ./.git ${root_subfolder[0]}
}
```

Usage

```bash
download_git_folder "git@github.com:foobar/Test.git" "master" "Test/bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a tool that might be exactly what you need:

1. Visit: https://techhelpbd.com/gitdown
2. Paste your Github folder link
3. Then you can easily download your Github folder

Give it a try and let me know how it works for you

Answer (score 1):

After so many annoying attempts I got this, this will allow you to download any directory/file from any branch/reference from any git repo, to any target you want even if you are already on a git repo, so this uses a combination of git archive in case it is supported, but obv github does not support it, so it falls back to a smart git clone that filters blobs, and then checks out. This creates a directory in a temporary directory and moves the files.

```bash
# Function to download specific files or directories from a Git repository without history
function download_from_git() {
  local git_remote="$1"
  local git_ref="$2"
  local git_path="$3"
  local target="$4"

  # Create a temporary directory next to the current directory
  temp_dir=$(mktemp -d temp-git-repo-XXXXXXXX)

  # Attempt to download the specified file or directory using git archive
  if git archive --remote="$git_remote" "$git_ref" "$git_path" | tar -x -C "$temp_dir"; then
    # Check if the git_path is a directory or a file
    git_path_exists=$(ls -d "$temp_dir/$git_path" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ -z "$git_path_exists" ]; then
      echo "Error: The specified Git path does not exist in the repository."
      return 1
    fi

    if [ -d "$temp_dir/$git_path" ]; then
      mkdir -p "$target"
      mv "$temp_dir/$git_path/"* "$target/"
    else
      mkdir -p "$(dirname "$target")"
      mv "$temp_dir/$git_path" "$target"
    fi
  else
    # Clone the repository with the specified branch or ref in the temporary directory
    git clone --depth 1 --branch "$git_ref" --filter=blob:none "$git_remote" "$temp_dir"
    cd "$temp_dir"

    git restore --source "$git_ref" -- "$git_path"

    cd - > /dev/null

    # Check if the git_path is a directory or a file
    git_path_exists=$(ls -d "$temp_dir/$git_path" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ -z "$git_path_exists" ]; then
      echo "Error: The specified Git path does not exist in the repository."
      return 1
    fi

    if [ -d "$temp_dir/$git_path" ]; then
      mkdir -p "$target"
      mv "$temp_dir/$git_path/"* "$target/"
    else
      mkdir -p "$(dirname "$target")"
      mv "$temp_dir/$git_path" "$target"
    fi
  fi

  # Clean up the temporary directory
  rm -rf "$temp_dir"
}
```

## Usage

```
download_from_git "https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack.git" "master" "npm" "./node-modules/wasm-pack/"
```

in this case you might notice it fetches the last head instead of just these files, while it is possible to just  fetch the last files it downloads way way slower! but in case you really want to just download the files, use:

```
    git clone -n --depth 1 --filter=blob:none "$git_remote" "$temp_dir"
    cd "$temp_dir"

    # Set the sparse-checkout to only include the required directory
    git sparse-checkout init --cone
    echo "$git_path" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

    # Download the required objects
    git checkout "$git_ref" -- "$git_path"
```

instead.

Hopefully this saves time to someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python and SVN to download a specific GitHub directory, here is the code that you would use:

```py
import validators
from svn.remote import RemoteClient

def download_folder(url):
    if 'tree/master' in url:
        url = url.replace('tree/master', 'trunk')

    r = RemoteClient(url)
    r.export('output')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = input('Enter folder URL: ')
    if not validators.url(url):
        print('Invalid url')
    else:
        download_folder(url)
```

You can check more details about this code and other GitHub search and download tips in this tutorial: https://python.gotrained.com/search-github-api/

Answer (score -1):

This answer is for a special case when you want a certain file from a repository.

A short answer can be found [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/Download-from-Github/). You should change the URL to this format:

```
https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/file.name
```

To explain it simply, enter your desired URL from GitHub. Add *raw* before GitHub in the URL address, and delete the blob from the address. For example, suppose you want to grab the CSV file in this address:

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv

You should change the URL to this one:

https://raw.github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv

Comment: The question was how to download a folder not a file. This method only works for files

Answer (score -8):

If the directoy you want to download is a separated library, it's better to create an other git repo, and then to use the git submodule function.

Of course, you have to be the owner of the initial repo you want