# Simple line plot from Pandas Dataframe - no plot window showing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am currently trying to plot (my first) very simple line chart from a Pandas 
dataframe.

My (partial) code is:

```
data = {'Date': dates,
    'Daily Return': daily_return,
    'Cumulative': cumulative}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Daily Return', 'Cumulative'])

ts = df[['Date', 'Cumulative']]

print ts.head()
print ""
print ts.dtypes
ts.plot()
```

And my output is:

```
        Date  Cumulative
0 2014-01-02  100.903375
1 2014-01-03  101.344302
2 2014-01-06  101.080674
3 2014-01-07  101.080674
4 2014-01-08  101.493248

Date          datetime64[ns]
Cumulative           float64
dtype: object
Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
```

showing that "ts" is a legitimate dataframe as I can print out its "head" call and its datatypes.

But no plot window appears - and I do not understand why.

The documentation (found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html) for plotting a Pandas dataframe suggests the following code:

```
In [2]: ts = Series(randn(1000), index=date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

In [3]: ts = ts.cumsum()

In [4]: ts.plot()
```

Why will my ts.plot() call not work - why is no plot window appearing?

I have searched many information sources and all of them suggest that extremely simple "dataframe.plot()" syntax but I just can not get it to work.

I receive no error message at all.

***UPDATE***

I cam across this post: [matplotlib plot window won't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear) and so...

I have run the following commands:

```
import matplotlib            
print matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
```

in my console window and get the following message:

```
Backend WXAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
WXAgg
```

Is this information at all relevant?

Comment: are you using ipython?  make sure you use the --pylab option

Comment: If you do `from matplotlib import pyplot` and then `pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3])`, do you see a plot?  If not, the problem is likely with how matplotlib is set up, and has nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: No, nothing shows when I do that - although I have matplotlib running fine in some other scripts that I have - I can even call a user defined plot function that I have defined in another imported module. I am using Pycharm as my environment - I do have iPython but I am not sure how to activate it in Pycharm

Comment: Have you tried typing pyplot.show() after doing BrenBarn's test?

Comment: Ok thanks!! so adding plt.show() after each .plot() call works - I can now plot both my pandas dataframe and other pyplot test plots as recommended above. But each successive plot only shows as each previous one is closed...how may I set it up so that if I have multiple dataframe.plot() calls all plot windows open at the same time rather than having to close one before I see the next?