# matplotlib using PyCharm on Windows won't plot graphs, no error

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(0, 10, 1)) #or "plt.plot(range(10))"
plt.show()
```

and it does nothing (except saying "Process finished with exit code 0" ). I am using PyCharm, on Windows 7, I installed matplotlib via PyCharm's package manager. I installed python 2.7 and PyCharm today (I practiced it for a month at codecadamy.com but I wanted to get accustomed to real conditions), so I am noob, and it can happen that the problem is trivial.

I tried various codes at matplotlib.org with no results.

Comment: `Process finished with exit code 0` means that it executed without an error. It's strange that a pop-up window doesn't appear. Try saving the figure using `plt.savefig` and checking if it did. Additionally `show` was intended to be used as a script more than as an interactive plot. Are you running that as a script or from some IDE/IDLE/REPL (write a command press enter...)? Try using `plt.ion()` and then repeating the commands to see if a plot appears. Disclaimer though, I don't use PyCharm.

Comment: I am running it as a script. I tried `plt.ion()`, nothing happens. I tried `plt.savefig("image.png")` it did not save it (i checked in the folder where the whole project is).

Comment: are you sure it saved it there? Can you write `import os` at the top and then `print(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)` right before you do the `plt.savefig`. The path it prints out is the one where the image is saved. If that doesn't work the best I can do for you is direct you to [PyCharm help forums](http://forum.jetbrains.com/forum/PyCharm)

Comment: I just run the wrong script, i did not expect that it would run old script if this one is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently i made the stupidest mistake ever. I had multiple tabs opened, and I constantly run the first one, instead of the one i should have. Should I delete question? I'm so embarrassed.

Comment: don't delete it, just mark your own answer correct and let it go. I think there's a time period of 48h before you can do that but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please delete it. I voted to close. Keeping this question around won't help anyone. It will only waste people's time who are having a real problem that happens to hit on the same key words.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling python, and reinstalling again.

Or check out this link, it's similar to your question: 
[matplotlib plot window won't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear)

Comment: Thanks for response, i saw that link already. I turned out I made the stupidest mistake possible.