# Simple plot from python console

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

Using `anaconda` 3.6 under `Windows`, this program when executed from an `anaconda` `console`

```
python simple_plot.py
```

runs, but nothing displays:

```
#file simple_plot.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

If I add

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and run the program:

```
python simple_plot.py

(base) C:\Users\idf\Documents\Python Scripts>python simple_plot.py
  File "simple_plot.py", line 3
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I run this program

```
(base) C:\Users\idf\Documents\Python Scripts>python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())"
```

I get the output:

```
Qt5Agg
```

Not even simple print statements work once I include:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("hello world") #nothing shows on console
```

Output of `conda list`

```
(base) C:\Users\idf\Documents\Python Scripts>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Ivan Figueredo\Anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36he6757f0_0
absl-py                   0.3.0                    py36_0    anaconda
absl-py                   0.2.2                     <pip>
aiohttp                   3.2.1                     <pip>
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36hcd07829_0
anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.8.7                    py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36hfad2e28_0
appdirs                   1.4.3                     <pip>
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astor                     0.6.2                    py36_1    anaconda
astor                     0.6.2                     <pip>
astroid                   1.6.3                    py36_0
astropy                   3.0.2            py36h452e1ab_1
async-timeout             3.0.0                     <pip>
attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0
backports                 1.0              py36h81696a8_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36h79ab834_2
bazel                     0.14.0               h6538335_0
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36hd4cc5e8_1
bitarray                  0.8.1            py36hfa6e2cd_1
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h7e685f7_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h8a29ca5_0
bleach                    1.5.0                     <pip>
bleach                    1.5.0                    py36_0    anaconda
blosc                     1.14.3               he51fdeb_0
bokeh                     0.12.16                  py36_0
boto                      2.48.0           py36h1a776d2_1
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36hd119dfa_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h945400d_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
click                     6.7              py36hec8c647_0
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py36hb10d595_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0
comtypes                  1.1.4                    py36_0
conda                     4.5.8                    py36_0
conda-build               3.10.5                   py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
conda-verify              2.0.0            py36h065de53_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36he5d52c0_0
coverage                  4.5.1                     <pip>
cryptography              2.2.2            py36hfa6e2cd_0
cuda91                    1.0                           0    pytorch
cudatoolkit               9.0                           1
cudnn                     7.1.4                 cuda9.0_0    anaconda
curl                      7.60.0               h7602738_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
cython                    0.28.2           py36hfa6e2cd_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36hfa6e2cd_0
dask                      0.17.5                   py36_0
dask-core                 0.17.5                   py36_0
dataclasses               0.6                       <pip>
datashape                 0.5.4            py36h5770b85_0
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0
distributed               1.21.8                   py36_0
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
easygui                   0.98.1                    <pip>
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h3d2d736_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36hfa6e2cd_2
filelock                  3.0.4                    py36_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1
flask-cors                3.0.4                    py36_0
freetype                  2.8                  h51f8f2c_1
future                    0.16.0                    <pip>
gast                      0.2.0                    py36_0    anaconda
gast                      0.2.0                     <pip>
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.3.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0
glob2                     0.6              py36hdf76b57_0
greenlet                  0.4.13           py36hfa6e2cd_0
grpcio                    1.13.0                    <pip>
grpcio                    1.12.1           py36h1a1b453_0    anaconda
gym                       0.10.5                    <pip>
h5py                      2.7.1            py36h3bdd7fb_2
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2
html5lib                  0.9999999                py36_0    anaconda
html5lib                  0.9999999                 <pip>
ibpy2                     0.8.0                    py36_0    tibkiss
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
idna-ssl                  1.1.0                     <pip>
imageio                   2.3.0                    py36_0
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0
ipython                   6.4.0                    py36_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0
ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py36_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0
itsdangerous              0.24             py36hb6c5a24_1
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0
jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_1
jinja2                    2.10             py36h292fed1_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
jupyterlab                0.32.1                   py36_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.5                   py36_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h12c3424_0
lapack                    3.6.1                         1    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hd1c21d2_0
libcurl                   7.60.0               hc4dcbb0_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0
libprotobuf               3.5.2                he0781b1_0    anaconda
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                hb8ad9f9_1
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0
llvmlite                  0.23.1           py36hcacf6c6_0
locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1
logger                    1.4                       <pip>
lxml                      4.2.1            py36heafd4d3_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  2.6.11                   py36_0    anaconda
Markdown                  2.6.11                    <pip>
markupsafe                1.0              py36h0e26971_1
matplotlib                2.2.2            py36h153e9ff_1
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hb41005a_1
menuinst                  1.4.14           py36hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.3            py36hfa6e2cd_1
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h57e144c_4
mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py36h452e1ab_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h9258bd6_0
more-itertools            4.1.0                    py36_0
mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hacc8adf_2
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36he980bc4_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multidict                 4.3.1                     <pip>
multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py36_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0
nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0
nose                      1.3.7            py36h1c3779e_2
notebook                  5.5.0                    py36_0
numba                     0.38.0           py36h830ac7b_0
numexpr                   2.6.5            py36hcd2f87e_0
numpy                     1.14.3           py36h9fa60d3_1
numpy-base                1.14.3           py36h555522e_1
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
odo                       0.5.1            py36h7560279_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0
opencv                    3.3.1            py36h20b85fd_1
openjdk                   8.0.121                       1
openpyxl                  2.5.3                    py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2o               h8ea7d77_0
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0
pandas                    0.17.1                    <pip>
pandas                    0.23.0           py36h830ac7b_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
parso                     0.2.0                    py36_0
partd                     0.3.8            py36hc8e763b_0
path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_0
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0
pillow                    5.1.0            py36h0738816_0
pip                       18.0                      <pip>
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1
plotly                    2.7.0                     <pip>
pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hc7daf1e_0
ply                       3.11                     py36_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0
protobuf                  3.5.2            py36h6538335_0    anaconda
protobuf                  3.6.0                     <pip>
psutil                    5.4.5            py36hfa6e2cd_0
ptan                      0.3                       <pip>
py                        1.5.3                    py36_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h413d8a4_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36hfa6e2cd_8
pycuda                    2017.1.1+cuda9288           <pip>
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36h74b6da3_0
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36h0b975d6_0
pyglet                    1.3.2                     <pip>
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0
pylint                    1.8.4                    py36_0
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36h6538335_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h1aa27d4_0
PyQt4                     4.11.4                    <pip>
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0
pytables                  3.4.3            py36he6f6034_1
pytest                    3.5.1                    py36_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.2                      py36_0
pytest-astropy            0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-cov                2.5.1                     <pip>
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-qt                 1.2.2                     <pip>
pytest-remotedata         0.2.1                    py36_0
python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0
python-magic              0.4.6                     <pip>
pytools                   2018.5.2                  <pip>
pytorch                   0.4.0           py36_cuda91_cudnn7he774522_1  [cuda91]  pytorch
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36hc649158_0
pywin32                   223              py36hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.1                    py36_0
pyyaml                    3.12             py36h1d1928f_1
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36hfa6e2cd_1
qt                        5.9.6            vc14h62aca36_0
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0
qtpandas                  1.0.3                     <pip>
qtpy                      1.4.1                    py36_0
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4371aae_1
rope                      0.10.7           py36had63a69_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36hfa6e2cd_1
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36hfa6e2cd_1
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36h9b69545_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                39.1.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h17d0c80_0
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
sklearn                   0.0                       <pip>
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0
sortedcollections         0.6.1                    py36_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.10                   py36_0
sphinx                    1.7.4                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36hbbac3d2_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36hb5e5916_1
spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py36ha85dd04_0
sqlite                    3.23.1               h35aae40_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h452e1ab_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py36h96708e0_0
tastyworks                1.0.0                     <pip>
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h30f5020_0
tensorboard               1.8.0            py36he025d50_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            1.8.0                h21ff451_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu-base       1.8.0            py36h376609f_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                     <pip>
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0
tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_3    anaconda
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    anaconda
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
websockets                6.0                       <pip>
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
win_unicode_console       0.5              py36hcdbd4b5_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36he5f5981_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h1cb58dc_1
xlsxwriter                1.0.4                    py36_0
xlwings                   0.11.8                   py36_0
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
yarl                      1.2.6                     <pip>
zeromq                    4.2.5                hc6251cf_0
zict                      0.1.3            py36h2d8e73e_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2

(base) C:\Users\idf\Documentidfs\Python Scripts>
```

If I launch a normal DOS console and then `activate` `python`:

```
C:\Users\idf>"..\idf\Anaconda\Scripts\activate.bat"
```

and try running `simple_plot.py`, same behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your [backends](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). It seems something is broken there (or missing). Maybe something like ```conda install qt``` (i did not check the package name!) would be enough. Maybe add the output of ```conda list``` for the experts here. **edit:** `nothing shows on the console once I include "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" not even simple print statements. – Ivan 5 mins ago` this should be part of your question (not a hidden comment) as this should change the things to look for!

Comment: Installed it. Wasn't installed. But still no plot.

Comment: I modified the post.

Comment: You report that the backend is Qt5Agg when in (base) environment. But when running your script, are you also in that (base) environment? I.e. `(base) > python script.py`?

Comment: When I launch an anaconda console from the start menu, I automatically get a console with a  "base"

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. So I guess you need to find out why there is nothing printed. As long as this persists, it's probably not worth investigating why plots are not shown. I would try by creating a mostly empty environment and check if the same issue is present.

Comment: Ok. Actually, I don't even know what "base" means. I will investigate how to get a "mostly empty environment" console.

Comment: Also, what happens if you `activate` the conda environment outside of the anaconda cosole and run the script from terminal? Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQCqv.png)?

Comment: See modified original post. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. See modified post. This is __not__ running in a GUI. It is a python program run from an anaconda command line.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. This is the line that displays plots for anaconda.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear

Comment: nothing shows on the console once I include "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" not even simple print statements.

Comment: You're not getting any output for `print matplotlib.rcParams['backend']`?

Comment: Nope. Nothing prints if I include matplotlib

Comment: what happens when you run the code normally? Like write the code in an editor and then run the python code from command prompt? Do you get the plot then?

Comment: THAT IS how I have been running it!

Comment: Did anything work? I apologize but I'm not very experienced with how anaconda works on windows.