# Matplotlib window doesn't show up, with TkAgg installed

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

I run this script in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
```

I get a nice plot as an output. I run this debug.py from terminal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

./debug.py doesn't give a plot. **My cursor changes shape**, it becomes a cross pointer, but I don't get any plot, and I don't get back my terminal prompt.

Following the recommendation [given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13155030/8565438), I run in a local python3 shell this:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print(matplotlib.rcParams['backend'])
```

The output is **TkAgg**, as it should be, based on [the answer to the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13155030/8565438).

Why I don't get a matplotlib window then?

Comment: If debug.py is this:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(matplotlib.rcParams['backend'])

and I run it, I don't get an output, just the changed-shape cursor.

Comment: `python3 debug.py`

Comment: @Goyo, with this debug.py:

`import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.rcParams['backend'])`


I get TkAgg as output. With debug.py being this:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()`

I get a window, as I wanted. Maybe I need to run my scripts python3 myscript.py, rather than ./myscript.py, though I dont understand why that'd be the case.

Comment: Because your shell does not know that `debug.py` is intended to be run by python3. Why should it?