# Why the ax.plot can not show in terminal in Windows by using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

You can see I am using `ax.plot` but nothing happened.

Comment: you have to call `plt.show()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib plot window won't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `plt.show()` when you've run all of your graph creation code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x= np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]