# How do you install numpy when you're not a superuser?

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I've downloaded the python binary file and then opened it in my home folder using

```
tar xzvf Python-2.7.3.tgz
```

This seems to work and when I run

```
~/Python-2.7.3/python
```

it works  great. However when I try to import numpy, apparently it is not included. I've downloaded the numpy binary and opened it in my home directory but python still will not find it. Is there somewhere special that I have to put the numpy folder so that Python will find it?

Comment: You won't have the Python stdlib this way, either. You're in for a whole lot of pain... maybe you can get the admin to install it for you?

Comment: Did you try what was listed in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7465532/1343005

Comment: It's unlikely, I'm not the only person using the computer and they're doing me a big favour letting me use it so I'd rather not annoy them!

Comment: does the system have python installed already, or do you *need* to use a local version?

Comment: the computer has python 2.5 installed already but I need python 2.6 or above really

Answer (score 1):

Use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) to install Python into your $HOME folder:

```
$ pythonbrew install 2.7.2
```

Then switch your current shell to use your local Python install:

```
$ pythonbrew use 2.7.2
```

Now you should be able to install NumPy:

```
$ pip install numpy
```