# PYTHONBREW: numpy installed but package not found

Tags: python, numpy, pythonbrew

I have some pyhton-scripts which are working perfectly on my local computer, but as you would guess, not so good on the server!

I wanted to use "pythonbrew" since at the server I have only Python 2.7.6 installed, but I need hdf5-package running ... OK

I installed **pythonbrew** (according to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew/) and switched to version 2.7.10 (as I use on my local computer).

Now I got some "numpy-issues". So I installed **numpy** with pip successfully (according to [How do you install numpy when you're not a superuser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364203/how-do-you-install-numpy-when-youre-not-a-superuser) and https://gist.github.com/audy/4012573), however, when I am running the programme:

```
pythonbrew py startup.py
```

I got the error message saying **numpy** *was not found* ...

I really have no clue what I am missing here? I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's look pythonbrew no longer in active development. They are suggesting to use https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv. However, if you are going to use numpy heavily in the production environment, I suggest you to use https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda  distribution. It can install without  affecting to the system python installation. You can use conda package manager that comes with Anaconda to install numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself how to run a python script with `pythonbrew` properly!

According installation guide for pythonbrew (see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew/), the following line should be used to run a script:

```
pythonbrew py myprogramm.py
```

However, **I can run my script by using `python` instead of** `pythonbrew py`:

```
python myprogramm.py
```

I cannot give an explanation for that, sorry. But maybe other people can. It is just working very well like this and I can use python and all packages normally!

Further instructions of how to use `pythonbrew`, installing or switching between different version etc., see the link to the installation guide I posted above!

*More details about `pythonbrew` and usage (from my perspective of view):*

The installation guide I mentioned explains step by step how to install `pythonbrew` in your home directory (e.g. on a server) and helps to set up python on a system where you are not superuser (e.g. a server where you are allowed to run scripts but not to execute any further installations!).

I had the problem that I needed a more up to date python-version and the server where the data is located is equipped with an older version. The other half of the story is that I also needed some packages (e.g. `h5py` or `cosmolopy`) which are also not installed at the server.

For me the easiest and perfectly working solution to that problems was to use `pythonbrew` and install it at my home directory on the server!