# Install python module on university computer

Tags: python, module, installation, local

I am trying to install dropbox on my university host, and that requires python module `docutils`. So, after downloading the module and running `python install.py` I get the following output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running build_data
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils': Read-only file system
```

Not surprising really, I can't do any writing outside my home directory. My question is - is there a way to install it in my home folder?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install python modules without root access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access)

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of pip, one way to do it is:

```
pip install --user project
```

Comment: Hey, I tried 'pip install -t ./docutils docutils-0.10.tar.gz' - got a lot of warnings but also 'Successfully installed docutils'. When running dropbpx ./configure I have the same problem - ot doesn't recognize the module. Does pip let python interpreter know that there's a module isntalled locally, or do I have to specify it when I import it?

Comment: `-t` requires an install location; `--user` should put it somewhere that Python already looks for modules (where possible).

Comment: So if I type '--user ~/modules' flag I tell python to look for modules in '~/modules'?

Comment: no, `--user` doesn't take an argument; pip and python know where your user python modules directory should be.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to circumvent system level modifications/additions when acquiring python modules is to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and its wrapper, to make it easier, [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), along with pip. Perhaps these are already installed? Try

```
$ mkvirtualenv dropboxEnv # or whatever you want to call it
$ workon dropboxEnv       # to activate the virtual environment
```

and/or

```
$ pip install docutils
```

if you don't have pip you can first try

```
$ easy_install pip
```

AFAIK, a virtualenv is the only way to "install" a module into your home folder. Trying to get virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper installed might be a good option. If those aren't already installed, you might try to find someone to install those on your machine system-wide, then you would be able to create any virtualenvs and install any modules you want into your home folder.

Comment: `virtualenv` is convenient but not the only way to install a Python module into your home folder.  An other answer mentions the `--user` configuration option supported by Distutils and pip.  You can also use the `PYTHONPATH` enviornment variable or dynamically `sys.path`.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about the --user tag. Thanks. I am aware of PYTHONPATH, but what do you mean by "you can also use the PYTHONPATH environment variable?" in this scenario?

Comment: You can install Python modules in any directory and then set `PTYHONPATH` to add that directory to the search path Python uses when importing modules.  There are times when that may be more appropriate than using a `virtualenv`.  But, for many use cases, `virtualenv` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded version try this

```
python setup.py install --user
```