# Android Market API - Python ImportError: No module named google.protobuf

Tags: python, google-play

Based on [Python-API](https://github.com/liato/android-market-api-py) the requirements I have configured and installed the protocol buffers (as mentioned in http://worthynote.blogspot.com/2011/05/protobuf-compiler-on-mac.html ) and python 2.7. When I ran the command

```
python examples.py
```

and still faced the error:

```
 File "examples.py", line 3, in <module>
import market_proto
File "/Users/siddharthan64/Downloads/android-market-api-py-master/market_proto.py", line 3, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/):

```
sudo pip install protobuf
```

I had the same problem, which is how I found your question, and this fixed it.

Comment: Glad this finally works.  Previous versions were not `pip`-installable.

Comment: why do you need to sudo?

Comment: @Guig You will need sudo if your python is installed under root directories. If your python is installed under your home (or somewhere you own permissions) you don't need sudo. In such cases you need to specify pip to install under the "user" location: `pip install --user module_name`. You can check more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access.

Comment: What if I get the import error, but protobuf is already installed?

Comment: Ah I just realize that my Cellar/python is called instead of my bin/python

Answer (score 2):

Use conda, if you use anaconda and juypter

```
conda install -c conda-forge protobuf=3.2.0
```