# how to include updated library in python code without root access?

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib

I am working remotely on university systems.I wanted to include python's matplotlib1.1 and university system has matplotlib 0.98.
I did according to this post
[How to install python modules without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access)

```
-bash-4.1$ easy_install  --install=$HOME/lib/python2.6/site-packages matplotlib
Searching for matplotlib
Best match: matplotlib 0.98.3
Adding matplotlib 0.98.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /opt/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Processing dependencies for matplotlib
Finished processing dependencies for matplotlib
```

But still I am not able to use modules in new version
I am getting `importerror` for animation which is there only in updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following import to import a specific version.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("matplotlib==0.98.3")
import matplotlib
```