# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everytime I try to delete a file using `os.remove()` in Python 3.5.1, I get this message `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

And here is that simple code:

```
def clean_thrash(path):
    dirlist=get_dirlist(path)
    for f in dirlist:
        fullname=os.path.join(path,f)
        if fullname == os.path.join(path,"thrash.txt"):
            os.remove(path)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            clean_thrash(fullname)
```

Didn't even delete a single file in the directory or sub-directory.

Comment: You are trying to remove a directory not file. `os.remove()` removes file with given path not directory

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif

Answer (score 14):

I too had this problem, and after searching found a good solution.

Essentially, before calling `os.remove(file_name)` we need **change file permissions**.

1. `import stat`
2. Before calling `os.remove`, call `os.chmod(file_name, stat.S_IWRITE)`

For example:

```
import os
import stat

def clean_thrash(path):
    dirlist=get_dirlist(path)
    for f in dirlist:
        fullname=os.path.join(path,f)
        if fullname == os.path.join(path,"thrash.txt"):
            os.chmod(fullname , stat.S_IWRITE)
            os.remove(fullname)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            clean_thrash(fullname)
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using windows, you can simply do:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(directory_path)
```

**Hope this works!**

Answer (score 1):

You have to be administrator user if you are on Windows or have to have sudo permissions if you are on Linux. 
try running code with `sudo`

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32199615/6356497

Comment: Thank You for the response..+Revaz

Comment: I fixed it by replacing os.remove(path) by os.remove(fullname)