# Installation issues with Tensorflow; PermissionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I've been having a bit of difficulty installing tensorflow onto my computer, and would like some advice on where to go from here. To be clear, I am trying to install on Windows [using the advice for anaconda in windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) from the tensorflow website, and I am stuck at part 4 of installing the version without GPU support.

At first, I was having a TypeError, where parse() got an unexpected keyword ([the issue in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco)). So I ran the conda install suggestions which were provided in the thread.

After that, I successfully installed both and tried to run:

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`

Which ran for a bit, but then my command prompt stated that I had thrown a PermissionError and that access is denied ([the same error found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377138/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied)). To get past this, I tried opening Windows Powershell as an administrator instead, which still gave me this error. If you have any suggestions on what I could try next, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the traceback error I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 352, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Users\awm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    os.unlink(destfile)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\awm\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'`

Comment: Do you get a traceback leading up to the `PermissionError`? And if so could you post it? Either way, a not entirely uncommon problem on Windows is that the permissions on some directory, aka the Access Control Lists (ACL) were corrupted somehow, breaking write access (even for Administrators). I doubt it's anything particular to `tensorflow`. Can you `pip install` any other packages?

Comment: Traceback error added. Yeah, I can `pip install` other packages for the most part.

Comment: `sudo pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow` ?

Answer (score 0):

After restart of kernal and without loading any library try pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).