# How to get rid from this error while downloading tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

```
   Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
```

> while Downloading tenserflow using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` this link  caused this error

Comment: Might wanna check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows

Comment: are you able to install any other packages this way? It looks like you don't have write permissions in  `c:\\program files\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages`, can you check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PermissionError: pip upgrade from 8.1.1 to 8.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659180/permissionerror-pip-upgrade-from-8-1-1-to-8-1-2)

Comment: open cmd (run as administrator) and then install by pip command

Answer (score 0):

bassed on this last part of your traceback:

```
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

you dont have permission to create directories

start your commandline as admin and try again

Answer (score 0):

Open command with Administrator rights and run same command. To open cmd with admin rights just Right click on command prompt shortcut and choose "Run as Administrator". Then run the following command.

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```