# Can not update pip. Or install pip. windows 10 pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

Can not update or any commands with pip is not working. Shows this exceptions while updating:

```
Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-info\\description.rs
    t' -> 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-lpjr52z1-uninstall\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-inf
    o\\description.rst'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 559, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-info\\description.rs
t'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PermissionError: pip upgrade from 8.1.1 to 8.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659180/permissionerror-pip-upgrade-from-8-1-1-to-8-1-2)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing through the executable:

```
python -m pip install mitmproxy
```

Make sure that you run cmd as **admin**.