# Tensorflow with Python installation failed on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pip

While trying to installing tensorflow package by pip on window, following error messages appears, please guide to avoid these.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\wheel'
```

Comment: Oh, it is very tricky, I got it. Just run the console as 'Run as Administrator' rest things are easy and same. Done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)