# python pip installer error

Tags: python, pip

i am trying to install pyinstaller with pip it's giving me this error:

```
error: could not create 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\Lib\site-packages\future': Access is denied

----------------------------------------
```

Command ""c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-72kzy1b4\future\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-s9wqmmur-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-72kzy1b4\future\

Thanks to all people that will reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Windows PowerShell as administrator. *Rightclick >> Run as Administrator*

Comment: Check as answered so people won't waste time viewing your solved problem.