# Could not install Open-CV due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I run `pip install opencv-python`, I get

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\redactedusername\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-wrckbxoo\opencv_python-4.0.0.21-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl':
>   Check the permissions.

I've tried `pip install -user opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-python --user` but no luck. Any ideas?
**And yes, I've tried using Administrator Command Prompt**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32199615/5099964, it is a good idea to google the error code, these kind of questions are usually answered

Comment: `pip install opencv-python --user` I don't know where you got `pip -user install packageName` but that doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)

Comment: Tried it all, researched it all. Unfortunately, You are of no help either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif check this one

Comment: use a virtualenv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manually downloaded the wheel file from this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)

And installed it through command prompt using

`pip install <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on "Command Prompt" and then "Run as administrator" that should do the trick