# Unable to upgrade pip through cmd

Tags: python, pip

[This is the error I am getting in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etwer.png)

the pic of the error I am getting.

Comment: Did you check permissions as shown in the error message?

Comment: How to check the permission

Comment: It says it in your picture. Use the `—user` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+access+is+denied

Answer (score 0):

Try

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip3 install -U pip (for Python 3.x)

pip install -U pip (for Python 2.7)

easy_install -U pip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

It's permission issue. Need to add `--user` flag to the command.