# pip install pyproj fails with PermissionError

Tags: python, pip, pyproj

I am tearing my hair out here! I have this working in Gentoo on my main PC, now moving the program to a different server. 
I am running Ubuntu 16 with a Python 3.7 Virtual Environment setup. I am in the venv environment. 
I have set the PROJ_DIR to point to `venv/` folder with a folder there as `bin/proj` with 777 permissions.
`python3.7 -m pip install pyproj` fails with PermissionError
I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is) which is the same problem in Windows as well as some others. I have even tried sudo -H but that fails too.
I have installed some other packages without any problem at all. Why this one?

Here is the Traceback as requested

```
Collecting pyproj
  Using cached pyproj-2.6.0.tar.gz (524 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/bin/python3.7 /home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmptv31e14_
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-k21mhy0s/pyproj
  Complete output (34 lines):
  PROJ_DIR is set, using existing proj4 installation..

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 91, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-oz41ud89/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 148, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-oz41ud89/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 128, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-oz41ud89/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 250, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-oz41ud89/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 243, in <module>
      ext_modules=get_extension_modules(),
    File "setup.py", line 147, in get_extension_modules
      proj_dir = get_proj_dir()
    File "setup.py", line 60, in get_proj_dir
      check_proj_version(proj_dir)
    File "setup.py", line 20, in check_proj_version
      proj_ver_bytes = subprocess.check_output(proj, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
      **kwargs).stdout
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/bin/proj'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/bin/python3.7 /home/francis/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmptv31e14_ Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: "*tried `sudo -H` but that fails too*" With such a major problem we need to see more details. Full traceback, please!

Comment: I have added the Traceback above, too big for here.
Just set it up on a different Gentroo Server, no problems at all.

Comment: Did you run your prompt/shell as an administrator?

Comment: I am in Linux, so running as normal user with the venv enabled as per  the prompt
(venv) francis@pytroll64:~/bin/RWS_MeteosatSynopCreator_2$
It worked OK on my Gentoo, boxes why not Uubntu

Comment: I suspect you used `sudo -H` too much. Start repairing with `sudo chown -R francis /home/francis`

Comment: OK, Done That. But same problem, I have the permisions on the venv/bin/proj/ directory as 777.

Comment: I have given up, and going to use my Gentoo Box which works. Thanks to @phd  for responding