# Trouble installing pyautogui on windows 10

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm having trouble installing pyautogui, it gives me the following error. By the way, I'm new to python so if I'm not understanding something please explain it to me.

Thanks in advance!

> pip install pyautogui
> Collecting pyautogui
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/76/7a0ec1013bc3559b7438f6773cba05ffaec600b8989be2d621a144e39b50/PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz
> Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
> Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/4f/acb6a2d95260a4377885e40c167fd5df587630696a6a7934675f86aebb06/pytweening-1.0.4.tar.gz
> Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21 (from pyautogui)
> Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5 (from pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/70/c7a4f46dbf06048c6d57d9489b8e0f9c4c3d36b7479f03c5ca97eaa2541d/PyGetWindow-0.0.9.tar.gz
> Collecting mouseinfo (from pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/fa/b2ba8229b9381e8f6381c1dcae6f4159a7f72349e414ed19cfbbd1817173/MouseInfo-0.1.3.tar.gz
> Collecting Pillow>=6.2.1; python_version == "3.8" (from pyscreeze>=0.1.21->pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/59/97618ad67fc0639ed588c60cfe9d91417f7bae8c87bbe7c7784b0ffdb9f1/Pillow-9.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
> Collecting pyrect (from pygetwindow>=0.0.5->pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/04/2ba023d5f771b645f7be0c281cdacdcd939fe13d1deb331fc5ed1a6b3a98/PyRect-0.2.0.tar.gz
> Collecting pyperclip (from mouseinfo->pyautogui)
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/2c/4c64579f847bd5d539803c8b909e54ba087a79d01bb3aba433a95879a6c5/pyperclip-1.8.2.tar.gz
> Installing collected packages: pymsgbox, PyTweening, Pillow, pyscreeze, pyrect, pygetwindow, pyperclip, mouseinfo, pyautogui
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\python38\Lib\site-packages\pymsgbox'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is

Comment: I figured it out, I had to use the py -m pip install pyautogui command.

Answer (score 1):

The error actually gives you your answer by their recommendation to use the --user option. I run into this as well, if you want to install something without admin privileges. Just add the --user flag to the end of your pip command. This will limit the installation to the current user and not require administrator privileges.
Try this:

```
pip install pyautogui --user
```

The second error also gives you the answer of what to do.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or, if needed...

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```