# Getting "[WinError 5] Access is denied" error while trying to restore from YAML file

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

Getting error from the topic:

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Zanzibar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-4iailnro\jupyter-qtconsole.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

What I already tried:

1. Start anaconda prompt as admin
2. Clear Temp directory (Windows 10 PC)
3. Reload computer

Is there anything else I can try?

Here is content of YAML file:

```
name: C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\heart-disease-project\env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyio=3.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - babel=2.11.0=py310haa95532_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1=py310haa95532_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h9128911_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h2bbff1b_1002
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.5.7=h56e8100_0
  - certifi=2023.5.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h2bbff1b_3
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py310haa95532_0
  - comm=0.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - contourpy=1.0.5=py310h59b6b97_0
  - cryptography=39.0.1=py310h21b164f_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - debugpy=1.5.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - flit-core=3.8.0=py310haa95532_0
  - fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=ha860e81_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h8cc25b3_3
  - glib=2.69.1=h5dc1a3c_2
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.5=h9e645db_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.5=hd78058f_0
  - icc_rt=2022.1.0=h6049295_2
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - idna=3.4=py310haa95532_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=haa95532_3556
  - ipykernel=6.19.2=py310h9909e9c_0
  - ipython=8.10.0=py310haa95532_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - ipywidgets=8.0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310haa95532_1
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - joblib=1.1.1=py310haa95532_0
  - jpeg=9e=h2bbff1b_1
  - json5=0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jsonschema=4.17.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py310haa95532_8
  - jupyter_client=7.4.9=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_console=6.6.2=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_contrib_core=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_contrib_nbextensions=0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=5.2.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_highlight_selected_word=0.2.0=py310h5588dad_1005
  - jupyter_latex_envs=1.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_1002
  - jupyter_nbextensions_configurator=0.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_server=1.23.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab=3.5.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.19.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.5=py310haa95532_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py310hd77b12b_0
  - lerc=3.0=hd77b12b_0
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libclang=12.0.0=default_h627e005_2
  - libdeflate=1.17=h2bbff1b_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=hd77b12b_6
  - libiconv=1.16=h2bbff1b_2
  - libogg=1.3.5=h2bbff1b_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - libtiff=4.5.0=h6c2663c_2
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=he774522_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=hbc33d0d_1
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h2bbff1b_1
  - libxml2=2.9.14=h0ad7f3c_0
  - libxslt=1.1.35=h2bbff1b_0
  - lxml=4.9.1=py310h1985fb9_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - matplotlib=3.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.7.1=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310haa95532_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py310h2bbff1b_1000
  - mkl=2021.4.0=haa95532_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310ha0764ea_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - munkres=1.1.4=py_0
  - nbclassic=0.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - nbclient=0.5.13=py310haa95532_0
  - nbconvert=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - nbformat=5.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.6=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook=6.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.2=py310haa95532_0
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310hd213c9f_0
  - numpy=1.23.5=py310h60c9a35_0
  - numpy-base=1.23.5=py310h04254f7_0
  - openssl=1.1.1t=h2bbff1b_0
  - packaging=23.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pandas=1.5.3=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pcre=8.45=hd77b12b_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=9.4.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pip=23.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - platformdirs=2.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - ply=3.11=py310haa95532_0
  - pooch=1.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.36=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.36=hd3eb1b0_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pygments=2.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyopenssl=23.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=py310haa95532_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyrsistent=0.18.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - python=3.10.10=h966fe2a_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=py310haa95532_0
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytz=2022.7=py310haa95532_0
  - pywin32=305=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pywinpty=2.0.10=py310h5da7b33_0
  - pyyaml=6.0=py310he2412df_4
  - pyzmq=23.2.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - qt-main=5.15.2=he8e5bd7_7
  - qt-webengine=5.15.9=hb9a9bb5_5
  - qtpy=2.2.0=py310haa95532_0
  - qtwebkit=5.212=h3ad3cdb_4
  - requests=2.28.1=py310haa95532_1
  - scikit-learn=1.2.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - scipy=1.10.0=py310hb9afe5d_1
  - send2trash=1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - setuptools=65.6.3=py310haa95532_0
  - sip=6.6.2=py310hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py310haa95532_1
  - soupsieve=2.3.2.post1=py310haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.41.1=h2bbff1b_0
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - terminado=0.17.1=py310haa95532_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tornado=6.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - typing-extensions=4.4.0=py310haa95532_0
  - typing_extensions=4.4.0=py310haa95532_0
  - tzdata=2022g=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=1.26.14=py310haa95532_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py310haa95532_1
  - websocket-client=0.58.0=py310haa95532_4
  - wheel=0.38.4=py310haa95532_0
  - widgetsnbextension=4.0.5=py310haa95532_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py310haa95532_2
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - xz=5.2.10=h8cc25b3_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=h8ffe710_2
  - zeromq=4.3.4=hd77b12b_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_0
  - zstd=1.5.2=h19a0ad4_0
  - pip:
      - qtconsole==5.4.0
      - seaborn==0.12.2
prefix: C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\heart-disease-project\env
```

Here is full log from Anaconda console:

```
(base) C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\diabetes_prediction>conda env create --prefix ./env -f C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.1.0
  latest version: 23.7.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.7.3



Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: |
/

    Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py


done
Installing pip dependencies: \ Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Users\\Zanzibar\\Desktop\\diabetes_prediction\\env\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Users\\Zanzibar\\Desktop\\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt', '--exists-action=b']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting qtconsole==5.4.0
  Using cached qtconsole-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting seaborn==0.12.2
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (293 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets!=5.2.1,!=5.2.2 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (23.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qtpy>=2.0.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy!=1.24.0,>=1.17 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.25 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=7.23.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (8.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline>=0.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: debugpy>=1.0 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: comm>=0.1.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (305.1)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib!=3.6.1,>=3.1->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25->seaborn==0.12.2->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.30 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.36)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.30->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asttokens in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: executing in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pure-eval in c:\users\zanzibar\desktop\diabetes_prediction\env\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole==5.4.0->-r C:\Users\Zanzibar\Desktop\condaenv.ribjy45t.requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.2.2)
Installing collected packages: seaborn, qtconsole
  Attempting uninstall: qtconsole
    Found existing installation: qtconsole 5.4.3
    Uninstalling qtconsole-5.4.3:
      Successfully uninstalled qtconsole-5.4.3

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Zanzibar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-4iailnro\\jupyter-qtconsole.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)

Comment: One answer I found here says: "Even you run from Administrator, it may not solve the issue if the pip is installed inside another userspace". OK, maybe I have this case. And he suggested to use the following comand:  "python -m pip install -U pip --user". But in my case I'm not using pip directly. I'm launching restoring  from yaml file. Is there a way to use kind of "--user" attribute or some other way to resolve it?

Comment: sorry, I don't use Windows except for gaming. maybe others can help you! on a side note, did you try to use a virtual env? it might help

Comment: Try to move the two packages under `pip` to the list of conda packages. They should be available from the conda channels.