# Error while installing beautfulsoup on my mac os

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup on my macOS. While installing i m getting below.

And also I tried with python setup.py install, but getting same error

Please help me to resolve this

```
bash-3.2$ easy_install /Users/SJV/Downloads/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1/beautifulsoup4.egg-info
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-620.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using root? Try:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4  # will ask your sudo password
```

Or login as root before run `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

---

Also, install it in [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) or [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465532/5299236) can without root permission(if you don't have root permission).