# Python Elasticsearch urllib3 exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, urllib3

I have to use python-elasticsearch library on a machine where I could only execute programs.  I am trying to use elasticsearch module by appending sys.path as mentioned below. I am facing below issue. It looks like the problem related to what is mentioned here 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/253 . But how do I resolve this when I dont have sudo access or any sort of upgrade access.

**Note :**I don't have sudo access on this machine so I cannot have venv, pip etc.

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0')
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0/elasticsearch/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from .client import Elasticsearch
      File "/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from ..transport import Transport
      File "/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .connection import Urllib3HttpConnection
      File "/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0/elasticsearch/connection/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .http_urllib3 import Urllib3HttpConnection
      File "/tmp/elasticpy/elasticsearch-2.3.0/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 2, in <module>
        import urllib3
    ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

Comment: Use a virtualenv.

Comment: As i suggested I dont have rights in the respective machine to create a venv

Comment: You don't need admin rights to create a virtualenv

Comment: It is Python 2.7 and I cannot use pip to install virtualenv  nor I dont have access to run setup.py as I dont have sudo access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23574970/1005215

Answer (score 0):

@nehal Thanks for your suggestion I was able to get it fixed. Please find the 
series of steps  I used to install

1. Used easy_install to install package pip
2. Appended PYTHONPATH
3. used pip to install virtualenv
4. Activated new virtualenv
5. Installed elasticsearch using pip

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/tmp/pytest/"
   easy_install  --install-dir /tmp/pytest/  pip       
   pip install virtualenv --prefix /tmp/pytest/
   export PATH="${PATH}:/tmp/pytest:/tmp/pytest/bin"
   export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/tmp/pytest/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
   cd /tmp/
   virtualenv venv
   source venv/bin/activate
   pip install elasticsearch
   ```