# Pip install "python setup.py egg_info" even inside of virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I've been getting this error consistently with random packages in my new installation. At first I thought it was just a problem with the OS, so I setup a virtualenv, yet even now I am still getting the same error. I've tried every solution online I could find relating to this error, from reinstalling pip, setup tools, and so on. The error occurs intermittently when I use pip install. Some packages install, others don't.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oyotjp0i/beautifulsoup/
```

Comment: what are the packages you need to install? do you have root access?

Comment: Have you tried using anaconda instead of pip ? Sometimes I've had some of these libraries fail with pip but install with conda

Comment: Also there are two or so questions already asked on this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info

Comment: Yes I've read pretty much every similar question about this error, but none of the ones I came across seemed to have the same issue inside of a Virtualenv. This has happened with over 10 different random packages I've needed to install, I haven't been keeping track. And yes @AshwaniKumarRahul I do have root access, or rather, I get the same error if I do sudo pip install or just pip install. Is it possible the error has to do with a folder permissions issue?

Comment: @vikingben I can't even install conda because I get the same egg_info error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uzx1sn24/conda/

Comment: What is the default python version, if python 3 then you need pip3..

Comment: Moreover you can go with local installation as you do not have root access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access

Comment: @AshwaniKumarRahul I get the same errors with the same packages whether I am using pip or pip3. I have my virtualenv setup with python3 as the default, so standard pip works to install packages for it, but either way I still get the same error with both pip's. Also what do you mean? - I do have root access.

Comment: sorry I misread  your comment. i thought you do not have.

Comment: I had the same issue, and in my case also even though python3 was default but pip was configured for python2, so i did fresh pip3 installation "sudo apt-get install python3-pip"
and used pip3 to install packages

Comment: "pip --version"  will give you output something like
"pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"   from the output you can identify whether it is configured for pythin2 or python3

Comment: @AshwaniKumarRahul this is the pip version inside my virtualenv "pip 9.0.1 from /home/zero/Desktop/PyEnv/py2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)" Outside of the virtualenv it is configured with 2.7. I had tried reinstalling pip the other day and didn't have much success. I get the same errors regardless of which pip I use, whether pip or pip3. I've tried other things outside of the virtualenv, such as reinstalling setup tools, or installing it via ez_setup. I've tried almost every answer I encountered in previous posts about this same error. Not really sure what to do :/

Comment: Please provide versions of pip and setuptools installed *inside* virtualenv and a package which fails to install with the error given. I suggest running pip in verbose mode by passing `-vvv` argument.