# Install a Python package that built for Windows and MacOS on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have currently used the python Package Larch (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/larch) on Windows. It works nicely and I am really impressed with its performance. To use the package with some large models I want to install it on a Linux server (Ubuntu 14.04.4) where I do not have the root permissions. Though knowing that the OS requirements for the package are Window or MacOS and being a beginner with Linux, I still gave it a try.

I was able to install python locally using anaconda distribution but when I used pip to install larch, I got the following message

**Could not find a version that satisfied the requirement larch (from version: ) 
No matching distribution found for larch**

So it seems to me that I can not just deliberately try to install the package on linux with out any additional work. I then tried to find solutions for my issue but I could not find any. Therefore I would like to ask if there is any workaround for my problem?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I am having the same problem, is it solved for you?

Comment: Hi Yijiao Liu. Sorry for my late reply. I did not know about your question and thus could not answer any sooner. I was not able to make Larch work on the Linux server and finally wrote my own code in tensorflow to estimate the models.

Comment: me neither, I tried but can not make it work on Linux server

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**

> larch does not support **python2.x**, and only support Windows, MACOSX.

For installing in Linux, I suggest to use `wine` to run windows python program with larch.

For more information about wine in Ubuntu. You can search with keyword such as *How To Run Windows Software on Ubuntu with Wine*

---

For installing in macosx. Making sure your environment have `python3`. You can use `which python3` to check that.

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then, without root permission, you can install package via `virtualenv`. (A workstation should provide this command)

```
$ virtualenv -p $(which python3) env
$ . env/bin/activate
(env) $ python -V
Python 3.x.x
```

And finally, you can install larch via pip.

```
(env) $ pip3 install larch
```

[For more information about virtualenv](http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/)

Comment: Hi Kir Chou! Thank you very much for your answer! I am using python 3.6. I will try to see if your solution works.

Comment: Hi Kir Chou, I did a little search to find out more about virtualenv and think that it is not the right solution for my problem. My default python is python 3.6. The pip that I used was the one that came with it. It seems to me that the code of larch was not written for linux platform.

Comment: I also tried to use your code snippet but I got the following error: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: I used python3.5.2 on macosx and it works well (I have installed larch just now), maybe it hasn't support 3.6 yet. Since you don't own the linux root, if python3.6 doesn't be supported, you need to ask the admin for lower python version.

Comment: From this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/larch, apparently, it only support python3.4, 3.5. And os is only for macos and windows

Comment: Hi Kir Chou, it works with python 3.6. I am using it on my windows work station :D. Yes, the os requirements are windows or macos as I described in my question and that why I try to find a workaround so that I can use it on linux :(

Comment: I have tried in CentOS with python3.6. It seems didn't work with pip. Then I also tried to install manually. Apparently there are lots incompatible source code in C. I personally think the only workaround is using service such as `wine` to run windows program in linux.

Comment: Additionally, `larch` might not be a popular package which has less than 10 stars, however I still encourage you to discuss with the authors and make a new issue to request this feature on its github repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time and effort, Kir Chou! I truly appreciate it! I am thinking about wine and virtualbox as well. But I am trying to find out if those two software can be installed locally without the root permissions. You are right, larch is not so popular right now since it is used for a very specific purpose. But it is a really nice and powerful package :)

Answer (score 0):

"Larch can be installed from source code. If not using Anaconda, this is necessary for Linux, and can be done for other systems as well.

The latest releases of the source code will be available from Larch releases (github.com). In addition, you can use git to grab the latest development version of the source code:git clone http://github.com/xraypy/xraylarch.git"  After unpacking the source distribution kit, installation from source on any platform is:

python setup.py install

**source**:http://cars.uchicago.edu/xraylarch/installation/index.html
edit: See this for doing this without root access
[How to install python modules without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response naga sai abhinay devarinti! The package you mentioned in your answer is not what I wanted. It is a different package :)

Comment: @Kratos1808 Oops :)

Comment: No problem! Thank you for trying to help ;)