# How to install Windows Python package/library on linux and use it

Tags: python, linux, windows, package, metatrader5

I want to install package MetaTrader5 on my Linux [Fedora], but this package is supported only for Windows.

**And my question is:** Is it possible to install Windows Python packages on Linux? and after installation import in my python file?

**My Solution**

1. install `wine` (learn more about [wine](https://www.winehq.org/))
2. download [python for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), than install with `wine <path to .exe>`
3. `wine pip install MetaTrader5` or another windows only library
4. (example) create virtual enviroment `wine venv <name project>` and select
5. than import library to file, install package [3] in your virtual enviroment and you can you use it.
6. run with `wine python <file.py>`

Comment: I don't think so. I think you'd need to port the native dependencies of that package to the platform (i.e., OS) you want to use it in.

Comment: what is the version of your fedora??

Comment: @fayez Fedora 32

Comment: @PedroBoechat I think so too, but is better to ask :) thx, for answer

Comment: python-only modules will just work.  If there is compiled code, you will need to rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

you can install `wine` to deal with the windows installer files in your fedora.

as per the doc, you can run the following comands one by one to install wine:

`sudo dnf clean all && sudo dnf update`

`dnf config-manager --add-repo https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/fedora/32/winehq.repo`

`sudo dnf install winehq-stable`

after that, to confirm the installation: run `wine --version` , this should be executed without any error.

lastly, dowmload the `mt5setup.exe` and open it with `wine`.

also, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031808/10918344

hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to use Wine.
Its simply to do with **CrossOver**, its more stable.
Meta Trader compiled for the Wine.
Ive use this thing. Work correctly Meta Trader and Meta editor.