# Python : read excel in python with default module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Python 2.6.6 version and I don't have access to install new modules like pandas,xlrd,xlwt.

I want to read Excel using Python . Is it possible to read Excel using Python with default modules present in Python.

Comment: Probably this can help you: [How to install python modules without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this link: http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/PYTHON/library/csv.html
you should be able to use `reader` and `writer` commands by importing csv. You can also define different delimiters:

```
import csv

FileReader = csv.reader(open('FileName.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')
```

Moreover, you can map the data you are reading into a dict using `DictReader`.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you are using an IDE ex. PyCharm then you can drag an drop the file in your workspace or project and open it like this --> `open("myfile.csv")` it will be opened as a csv (comma seperated value) 
2) otherwise, use --> the file complete path such as `open("User/Desktop/myfile.csv")`

in both cases use --> `with open(.....) as f:
                      for x in f:
                          write some code here..`
and in this case x represents an element or cell in your excel file

Comment: Not using PyCharm , on simple Unix