# Error in Installing pip

Tags: python

Trying to use Python to code games. First installed python version 3.7. The software was downloaded in users/admin/program files. Here I would like to clarify that this is on my personal PC where I have no installation restriction. Python 3.7 was installed without any problem.

Subsequently tried installing Pygame and Pygame Zero. Tried running python -m pip install -U pip and pip install pygame. It was not successful and gave the above error. After referring to some help on google and possible solution, used the option "--user". It worked but don’t know what it did.

Subsequently, tested Pygame zero by typing pgzrun user/document/name.py.  it is not getting executed. 
Below is the typed version on command prompt
“ QUOTE”
C:\Users\admin>pip --version
pip 18.0 from C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
Following message appears when tried pgzrun
C:\Users\admin>pgzrun C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python-games\Hello\Hello.py
'pgzrun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
“ UNQUOTE”

Trust this helps in identifying the issue.  Not sure, if the name of the location users/admin creating confusion as I have not defined any username other than the default.

regards,

While installing pip on windows PC, I am encountering this error

```
C:\Users\admin>python -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-10.0.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am not aware how the system permissions could be checked to ensure that the pip is installed correctly.

As of now, I tried using ""--user" option. It worked. But this does not seem to be the correct method. When I run pgzrun option on the command editor and call a python file (Hello.py), pgzrun does not get recognised.

Comment: Do you have installation permissions on the computer you are using?

Comment: what is `pgzrun`? please describe your issue in more detail (and probably remove the answer you linked to and post that here).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access) might help.

Comment: Pulled in the content from that link, and reworded the question accordingly.

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude  It is installed on my pC and no restriction of downloading

Comment: Did you open the Windows Command prompt as Administrator?  Start->cmd (right-click - run as Administrator). I know sometimes Windows 10 can be very picky about installing / modifying items in a non-elevated prompt.