# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: When I install AWS CLI

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

```
python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf                                                               71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 15.5MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d                                                               58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
```

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: This is because your user does not have write permission for the `/usr` folder, a well known pip issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access) for a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install access denied on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows)