# unable pip install mysqlclient & execute 'gcc': Permission denied

Tags: python, mysql, pip

Forgive me if I ask something really simple

I am setting up a Django app on a remote server, by Namecheap (no root access)

and my server information:

Apache Version: 2.4.38

MySQL Version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-cll-lve

Architecture: x86_64

Operating System: linux

Python: 3.7

Django: 2.1.7

Now I'm trying to had mysql DB connect to my django app.

But when I try installing connector **mysqlclient** with `pip install mysqlclient`

I had this error:

```
  $ pip install mysqlclient
  Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_19o3wdf/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp45bylejwpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1


  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_19o3wdf/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v39up5s1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Command "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_19o3wdf/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v39up5s1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_19o3wdf/mysqlclient/
```

I dive into an error message,(understand)

```
unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

it seem to show that error lies on permission of luinx system

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? highly, apprenticed

Comment: It seems not only you have root access — you don't have access to compiler (and very probably to other development tools). You cannot install Python modules without help from admins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied

means your user does not have permission to run the `gcc` C compiler.

This is pretty unusual, and it sounds like a (slightly ham-fisted) security measure on the server you're using. You will need to ask whoever administers the server for assistance.

Answer (score -1):

you must have root permission to run these type of commands usually. add `sudo` to your command:

```
sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I'm sorry shotgunner but I don't had root access

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access

Comment: @RookiesDJ. is `pip install --user mysqlclient` also fails ?

Comment: yes, I receive this error; **Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.**