# How do I resolve the permission denied error when trying to download a python library without sudo?

Tags: pip, python-3.6, centos7

I'm Setting up a server using Nginx and Gunicorn to host a laboratory website built with Flask.
This issue pertains to the lack of sudo privileges on the server issued by the school.
When i try to download the requirements libraries using the **pip3 install** command, the following error appears.

This is CentOS 7

```
(myenv) [abcde@mgWebDB01 user01]$ pip3 install flask-migrate
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 294, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 595, in __init__
    self._distro_release_info = self._get_distro_release_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 984, in _get_distro_release_info
    basenames = os.listdir(_UNIXCONFDIR)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 247, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 595, in __init__
    self._distro_release_info = self._get_distro_release_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 984, in _get_distro_release_info
    basenames = os.listdir(_UNIXCONFDIR)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc'
```

The following shows the **pip3 list** command execution.

```
(myenv) [abcde@mgWebDB01 user01]$ pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
click              8.0.4
dataclasses        0.8
Flask              2.0.3
importlib-metadata 4.8.3
itsdangerous       2.0.1
Jinja2             3.0.3
MarkupSafe         2.0.1
pip                9.0.3
setuptools         39.2.0
typing-extensions  4.1.1
Werkzeug           2.0.3
wheel              0.37.1
zipp               3.6.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 247, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 595, in __init__
    self._distro_release_info = self._get_distro_release_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 984, in _get_distro_release_info
    basenames = os.listdir(_UNIXCONFDIR)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc'
```

If there's anything that doesn't fit the required format, I'm truly sorry.
Thanks for reading..!!

I reached out to the administrator by phone, but unfortunately, they mentioned they can't provide sudo privileges.

I used **pip3 install --user flask-migrate** command but the result remains unchanged.

The installed list was installed when the root account was unintentionally accessed.
I can't use the root account anymore. Is there another way to install the requirements libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python modules without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access)

Comment: You got "*Permission denied*" on listing `/etc` — `pip` is trying to recognize Linux distribution. Ask your sysadmins to fix permissions on `/etc` — the directory and most files in it should be readable by anyone. But if your school wouldn't cooperate — ouch, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can only access it with my school account, so I'll test it out when it arrives tomorrow.