# How I can download files with Git

Tags: git

How I can download from my repository at Git?

I can upload and commit my sources, but, I don't know download from my repository.How I can this?

Comment: You mean `git pull`? http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-pull

Comment: you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218271/10000823

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for the ability to get latest from the remote repo?  If so it's just:

```
git pull origin master
```

where origin is the remote and master is the branch name.

Comment: I used your command, and the shell returned:


$ git pull Myorigin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Documents and Settings/Romulo/.ssh/id_rsa':
From github.com:andrezc/sincflex
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

reading the help file, I used the command:

git fetch --all

bit, don't work.


help-me pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaase

Comment: @André Looks like you were unblocked by the other answer. Correct?  I was under the assumption you had a local repo and a viable remote set up.  But if git clone worked, then apparently not.  Glad you are unblocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/.../linux-2.6
```

Just use `git clone`.

Comment: @André If my answer was correct, please specify it as an accepted answer. I see you haven't done that on any of your questions, even though you've received answers that works for you. That way it will be easier to find the solution to whatever problem was presented. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more information.