# git: download a folder

Tags: git

Is there a git command that allows me to download just a folder structure from a git repository?

My use case is that I have a build server that needs a 'scripts' folder as part of the build and I don't want it to clone the entire repository in order to checkout that folder. 'clone --depth 1' is not good either as other files in the source tree outside the scripts folder are pretty big.

Comment: You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218271/10000823 if the directories are really big, just use the second message part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

World of pain around this - and it's one of the few places where svn is better. Working with submodules wasn't fun.

In the end we've gravitated towards three options:

1. Use wget to grab the dat from github (using the raw file view)
2. Have upstream projects publish the required data subset as build artifacts
3. Give up and use the full checkout. It's big hit on the first build but unless you get lot of traffic, it's not too much hassle in
   the following builds.

Answer (score 1):

Put that folder in a submodule, and when you need it, clone the submodule only.