# Changing folder structure for Github repo zip download

Tags: git, github

Currently, if I were to download a repo through a link like this that's provided on any github repo (for example https://github.com/Shukaro/TekkitPlus/archive/master.zip) the folder structure ends up being master.zip/somefolder/repofilesandfolders. Is it possible to download the repo in such a way that the folder structure ends up as master.zip/repofilesandfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible currently. You have to unpackage and repackage manually to get the structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in a similar questionusing 3rd-party pages to download subfolders from a given github repo.

e.g. you could try [DownDir](https://downdir.vercel.app/)

Source-Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876089/2377961