# Downloading single file from Android Git

Tags: android, git

I want to modify the stock Launcher 4.2.2 APK to make the search bar look like it was in 4.0.4.

I need to download a file that was between Android versions. It is in Android Git in binary file, but I don't know how to get it.

The link is: ]https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/cc216bf678b05dbe25fd4e5d5c87359ae12658d6/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/workspace_bg.9.png

The rev is:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/cc216bf678b05dbe25fd4e5d5c87359ae12658d6

Can anyone help me to get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get a single file. To get the file you need to clone whole repository and get the file locally:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2 foo
cd foo
git checkout cc216bf678b05dbe25fd4e5d5c87359ae12658d6
```

First line downloads the repository to foo/ directory, last line sets foo to specified revision.

Comment: I did not receive mail notification and I thought no one answered. Thank you very much, I got downloaded it. :)

Comment: You can get single files if you try hard enough with modern git.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218271/10000823