# how to download a single directory from a git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a git repository by name "abc".
 It contains so many folders inside but I want to download only one folder from it. 
Can anyone please explain me how to do it.....
Thanks

Comment: Is your repository on github?

Comment: Checkout the same question answered on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/checkout-only-one-file-from-git.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. You have to clone the repository entirely to have access to a particular directory.

Comment: It is possible, you can find several solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo).