# Disabling drag-and-drop of text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a touch screen, and this makes it inconvenient for me to have drag-and-drop enabled in Notepad++. I never used drag-and-drop anyway.

However, I cannot find how to disable drag-and-drop for text in Notepad++. Is it possible to disable this?

Note that I am talking about text drag-and-drop. The only option I could find in the application's settings was related to the drag-and-drop of the tab bar.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** Build `Notepad++` from [here](https://github.com/Saurabh702/notepad-plus-plus)

**Note:** This question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/q/1145601/930253) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/1146519/930253). <strike>There is also an enhancement request [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2571) which is still open.</strike>.

The enhancement request was closed and here's the reason stated by the developer [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2571#issuecomment-606766474):

> Except that Scintilla makes it optional, it cannot be supported in
>   Notepad++. I encourage you do the feature request in [Scintilla project](https://www.scintilla.org/)

If one is building `Notepad++` from source, then I suggest the following workarounds.

Scintilla's editor component in `Notepad++` is actually responsible for the drag and drop feature (*this can be confirmed by using [SciTE](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)*). So one way to disable this feature is to modify the source code used to build the `SciLexer.dll` [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus#to-build-scilexerdll-with-boost).

Upon debugging the `Notepad++` project in Visual Studio, I found that this function `ButtonMoveWithModifiers` under [`Editor.cxx`](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/scintilla/src/Editor.cxx) is responsible for the drag and drop feature. 
Particularly [this](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/scintilla/src/Editor.cxx#L4763) snippet of code :

```
    if (inDragDrop == ddInitial) {
        if (DragThreshold(ptMouseLast, pt)) {
            SetMouseCapture(false);
            FineTickerCancel(tickScroll);
            SetDragPosition(movePos);
            CopySelectionRange(&drag);
            StartDrag();
        }
        return;
    }
```

So, commenting out the code block results to this

```
/*
if (inDragDrop == ddInitial) {
        if (DragThreshold(ptMouseLast, pt)) {
            SetMouseCapture(false);
            FineTickerCancel(tickScroll);
            SetDragPosition(movePos);
            CopySelectionRange(&drag);
            StartDrag();
        }
        return;
    }
*/
```

With this one change in the source code, build the new `SciLexer.dll`. You can keep the previous build of the dll as backup just in case you want to switch back to the Drag and Drop functionality.

However, if you are not building `Notepad++` from source and prefer to install via an executable, then note down the current version of your `Notepad++` and download the scintilla source for the same.

So if your `Notepad++` version is **v7.x.x**, then the URL which points to the scintilla source would be :

```
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/tree/v7.x.x/scintilla
```

To download a single folder or directory, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106012/10155936), or just download using this link:

```
https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/tree/v7.x.x/scintilla
```

(based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879691/10155936))

Modify the `Editor.cxx` as mentioned before and build the new dll as per the guide specified here:

```
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/tree/v7.x.x
```

**Note:** *Replace v7.x.x with your NPP version*

**Update:** The above method does not work for NPP release versions >= **v7.3.3**, due to this [`"Fix CIA Hacking Notepad++"`](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.3.3/) issue being fixed in **v7.3.3** and above. This is because the `SciLexer.dll` is digitally signed by the author of NPP project, so if the dll is tampered with, then `Notepad++` will complain saying:

> Library verification failed - Authenticode check failed: signature or signing certificate are not recognized.

[Source](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14054/certificate-required-for-building-notepad)

---

Here's a forked repository with the changes done for you, just build Notepad++ from [here](https://github.com/Saurabh702/notepad-plus-plus).

(*It should sync automatically with the parent repository due to this [app](https://github.com/apps/pull) however, if it doesn't due to some conflict then I will sync it manually as specified [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork)*)

**Note:** To keep the above forked repository in sync with the parent repository, the [Pull Github App](https://github.com/apps/pull) was used. Here's the `pull.yml`used for configuration of the forked repository:

```
version: "1"
rules:
  - base: feature
    upstream: master
    mergeMethod: merge
  - base: master
    upstream: notepad-plus-plus:master
    mergeMethod: hardreset
```

This keeps the master branch of the forked repository up-to-date with the parent repository. It also keeps the feature branch of the forked repository (*which contains the changes*) updated via the master branch of the forked repository by merging the same.

If the `Notepad++` Community ever decides to add or tweak this feature, the pull request generated by this App should lead to a merge conflict.

---

**Note:** If you are facing any certificate related issues when running the release config version of `Notepad++` from source, refer to [this](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14054/certificate-required-for-building-notepad/2).

Comment: Excellent investigative answer!