# Downloading a single directory from Git using Subversion

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to download [a folder from a Github Git repo](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/tree/master/08-PCA/data) using SVN and the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/1414455).

However, when I type:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/tree/master/08-PCA/data .
```

I get the error message:

> svn: E170000: URL
>   'https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/tree/master/08-PCA/data'
>   doesn't exist

Any ideas what is going wrong? I am using [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Don't know why you download a folder from git repo , but checkout the whole project directly seem works fine.

Comment: @johnMa The entire repo contains a lot of data, and I don't want to download everything.

Comment: First i think is a URL UTF8 issue but after i delete `08-PCA`, i got `URL 'https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/tree/master' doesn't exist
`, so i think maybe that's because the checkout url is not a subversion checkout url.

Comment: @johnMa You are correct, I was not constructing the URL correctly. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18324458/1414455) helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solves your problem:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/trunk/08-PCA/data .
```

Note the difference: not "tree/master", but "trunk".

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my URL was pointing to /tree but not the /branches.