# Try to copy specific folder from github with subversion failed

Tags: git, svn, github

I read [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo) and tries to download  [specific angular js source code](https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/tree/master/1.2.13) with the following svn command:

svn export https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org.git/1.2.13/ c:\angularVersion

But I get the following error:

svn: E170000: URL 'https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org.git/1.2.13' dosn't exist

What am I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause SVN and git have different directory structure, you may want this:

```
svn export https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org.git/trunk/1.2.13/
```