# How to download a folder from github?

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-14.04

I wished to download the mysite folder from this link:
https://github.com/username/repository/master/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)

Comment: Go to [DownGit](https://downgit.github.io) > Enter GitHub Folder URL > Download (no command, no tool, no fuss!)

Comment: github UI sucks. should have download folder option.

Comment: @MinhasKamal you should post that as an answer. Very useful and easy to use tool right there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a button `Download ZIP`. If you want to do a sparse checkout there are many solutions on the site. For example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository)

[image: downloadbutton]

Comment: download everything as a zip...then unzip, delete what you don't want, and rezip it and scp it to where you want it to go...

Comment: Or just simply download the whole repository and browse you desired files without installing or configuring any tool. (anyway your comment is a duplicate)

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. To be specific, "You can't download only a folder or a file," is wrong. 

See below for various correct solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will update the answer. I don't think the solutions below are correct, they just work. You can use `git` to download a sub-folder from a repository. Anyway, the repository hosting site github.com doesn't provide a way to do so without using any external tools.

Comment: Where is the `Download ZIP` button?  On the main repository page, click on the green `<> Code` button.  In the pop-up menu, you'll find the `Download Zip` option.

Answer (score 54):

You *can* **download a file/folder from github**

Simply use: `svn export <repo>/trunk/<folder>`

Ex: `svn export https://github.com/lodash/lodash/trunk/docs`

**Note**: You may first list the contents of the folder in terminal using `svn ls <repo>/trunk/folder`

(yes, that's svn here. apparently in 2016 you still need svn to simply download some github files)

Comment: I had to use `<repo>/branches/<branch_name>/<folder>` for a non-`master` branch, but otherwise worked flawlessly.

Comment: `<repo>/tags/<tag_name>/<folder>` also seems to work

Comment: Nice, thanks. Although I haven't found how to make it work for a specific Commit-ID. Eg. the older version of CLang on MSYS2 environment:
https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/aed89db4b0698dd4eaf3dc2ffd1c9541a61cc424/mingw-w64-clang

Comment: What the hell is SVN? xD

Answer (score 37):

You can use [Github Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) to get an archive link and `tar` to retrieve a specified folder.

#### Command line:

> curl https://codeload.github.com/***[owner]***/***[repo]***/tar.gz/master | \
>         tar -xz --strip=2 ***[repo]***-master/***[folder_path]***

---

**For example,**
if you want to download [examples/with-apollo/](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-apollo) folder from [zeit/next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js), you can type this:

```
curl https://codeload.github.com/zeit/next.js/tar.gz/master | \
  tar -xz --strip=2 next.js-master/examples/with-apollo
```

Comment: Nice! It's also optional with **WGET**, and with the regular **github archive url**: `wget -O - https://github.com/zeit/next.js/archive/master.tar.gz | tar -xz --strip=2 "next.js-master/examples/with-apollo"`

Comment: zip might works as well. `wget -c https://github.com/user/project/archive/master.zip`

Comment: This option is a poor one. If you only what images - it downloads whole repo first then trims it. Makes it less painful to individually download 15 images manually!

Comment: @JGFMK: maybe not rubbish, but just unclean solution which might also prove ineffective for some cases (eg. one mentioned by you: downloading several images out of hundreds).

Answer (score 24):

Use [GitZip online tool](https://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/). It allows to download a sub-directory of a github repository as a zip file. No git commands needed!

Comment: Why does it need write access to all my public repos?  Isn't this a security risk?

Comment: @JaredThirsk, but it doesn't. Can you tell us when did it happen in your case?

Comment: @gdrt When I click Get Token: Normal, Github asks: "This application will be able to read and write all public repository data. This includes the following: - Code, ..."

Comment: @JaredThirsk, you should provide API Access Token if the repository isn't public. If it is public, simply providing repository URL and clicking Download button will do it.

Comment: @gdrt Ok, I see.  It would be nice if there wasn't a popup expanded by default when going to that page, as well as the message "We recommended to get the token first and then do your actions."

Comment: Rare to find such an easy solution to what you want to do. This really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

### How to download a specific folder from a GitHub repo

Here a proper solution according  to this [post](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-can-I-download-a-specific-folder-from-a-GitHub-repo/m-p/88#M20):

- Create a directory

  ```
   mkdir github-project-name 
   cd github-project-name
  ```
- Set up a git repo

  ```
   git init
   git remote add origin <URL-link of the repo>
  ```
- Configure your git-repo  to download only specific directories

  ```
   git config core.sparseCheckout true # enable this
  ```
- Set the folder you like to be downloaded, e.g. you only want to download the doc directory from `https://github.com/project-tree/master/doc`

  ```
   echo "/absolute/path/to/folder" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
  ```

  E.g. if you only want to download the doc directory from your master repo  `https://github.com/project-tree/master/doc`, then your command is `echo "doc" > .git/info/sparse-checkout`.
- Download your repo as usual

  ```
   git pull origin master
  ```

Comment: The best answer of all! However, I believe there should no be "-f" in "git remote add origin", since "-f" means a immediate fetch from server, which should be avoided since only the "sparse" path is wanted!

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: in my case, I could see from `git pull origin`'s verbose that doing this downloaded the entire repository; but retained only the folder specified in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`. and using `https://downgit.github.io/` did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

## VSCode Integration for Github

Anyone like me browsing a github repository and want to download a folder from a repository from the browser, without any third party tools, you might use the vs code extensions of github.

**Step 1** Open the directory of the repository which you want to download in your browser.

**Step 2** In the url bar replace `.com` with `.dev`. For ex: `https://github.com/lodash/lodash` will become `https://github.dev/lodash/lodash`.

**Step 3** This will open a vs code interface of that git repository. Just right click on the folder which you want to download and then press download in option.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this method works only in Chrome/Chromium-based browsers. Firefox, while supporting the GitHub web IDE "in general" doesn't provide the download function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate the steps, the suggestions here will work only to an extent.

I came across this tool called `fetch` and it worked quite fine for me. You can even specify the release. So, it takes a step to download and set it as executable, then fetch the required folder:

```
curl -sSLfo ./fetch \
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/fetch/releases/download/v0.3.12/fetch_linux_amd64
```

```
chmod +x ./fetch
```

```
./fetch --repo="https://github.com/foo/bar" --tag="${VERSION}" --source-path="/baz" /tmp/baz
```

Comment: My vote goes to matrik.  This fetch utility is exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com//gruntwork-io/fetch.  Its a command line tool that not only fits the use case of the OP, but also provides many other useful features and switches for specifying exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency: [`cURL`](https://curl.haxx.se/) and [`7-Zip`](https://www.7-zip.org/).

```
curl {url for downloading zip file} | 7z a -tzip {project name}-{branch name}/{folder path in that branch}
```

for example:

```
curl https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_shimmer/archive/master.zip | 7z a -tzip flutter_shimmer-master/examples
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists also a nice browser extension which allows to dl files or folders

- [Enhanced-github](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhanced-github/anlikcnbgdeidpacdbdljnabclhahhmd)  extension for google-chrome browser
- [Enhanced-github](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/enhanced-github/eibibhailjcnbpjmemmcaakcookdleon) extension for ms-edge browser

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but I think it's fun! THis downloads all the files in a folder on github just using bash

(I used this to download the files for the postgresql tutorial but haven't tested it elsewhere)

```
curl "https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/tutorial" > test.html
links=$(cat test.html | grep -o \[^\"\]\*/blob/\[^\"]\*)
echo $links
echo "Now as a list.."
as_list=($links)
for (( i=0; i<${#as_list[@]}; i++ ));do
    download_link=("https://raw.githubusercontent.com${as_list[$i]}")
    echo "completing link: "
    echo "${download_link///blob/""}"
    wget "${download_link///blob/""}"
done
```

Explanation:

(1)the first line downloads the target folder as an html, and saves it as test.html

(2) the second line extracts all links to files on the page. This works by observing that links to files look like "/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore" on the html, we can get all those by looking for a 'blob' and getting all text upto the nearest quote " on each side

(3) we turn this into a list

(4)to finish the job, we observe that the url for the raw text version of the file looks slightly different , e.g. for the url "/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore", the url for the raw text file is "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgres/postgres/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore". Hence to process the data we turn "/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore" into "/postgres/postgres/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore", and finally into "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgres/postgres/master/src/tutorial/.gitignore"

P.S. sorry if my bash script is clunky - am a new linux user

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git archive`

```
git archive --remote=ssh://github.com/packageName.git HEAD path/to/my/dir | tar -x
```

Answer (score -3):

You can download the complete folder under Clone or Download options (Git URL or Download Zip)

1. There is a button of Download Zip
2. By using command you can download the complete folder on your machine but for that you need git on your machine. You can find the Git url uner

   git clone  https://github.com/url

Answer (score -8):

You can also just clone the repo, after cloning is done, just pick the folder or vile that you want.  To clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/somegithubuser/somgithubrepo.git
```

then go to the cloned DIR and find your file or DIR you want to copy.