# how to download all files in a private git repo in bash

Tags: bash, curl, github, wget

tried this:

```
TOKEN="bla"
wget -r --no-parent  --reject "index.html*" https://api.github.com/repos/organiztion/RepoName/contents/Framework/deploy_scripts/ --header "Authorization: token $TOKEN" --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw'
```

I am getting a file with a list of all the files in the directory. I want to the actual files and not a list.

Rather not write a bash script to loop over the files and download all of them.

I Prefer solutions that are "raw" meaning wget or curl and not svn ,please.

Answer (score 1):

Github give you the opportunity to grab a repo with SVN. SVN allow you to download the content of a repo subfolder only.

Take a look at this post: [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)

Comment: don't want to fill my user and password every time. does svn support ssh ? and do you know a way to do this via wget or curl?

Comment: Maybe this will work (I cannot try at the moment, let me know if it work): `svn checkout svn+ssh://github.com/foobar/Test/trunk/foo`. I think that it's not possible with curl or wget, but i'm not a git expert.