# Should I clone all data from git repository?

Tags: git

*git clone ssh://user@host:port/project.git*

I have to change several files in the web project with Git
and don't need to have all data at my hdd.

**What command should we use to edit a couple of files via Git ? 
Or is it impossible?**

P.S.:  i'm newbie for Git,  that would be fine if you also tell me, what should be wrote instead of  "project.git" (how to get project name?)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git has nothing to with how you changed your files. It only interested in the changes made, it tracks them and stores them for you. You can download some parts of the projects with some open source [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo) . But, you cannot push the changes back.

If you want to change some files easily without downloading the whole project, you may want to use the web browser interface and commit from there. Otherwise, I think you need to download the whole project. Maybe this will help you if you are using github like interface.

https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/

Comment: No problem, if that works for you could you please accept and upvote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: i would be greatful if you answer for another part of this question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616208/trying-to-clone-git-is-project-name-incorrect