# Trying to clone git - is project name incorrect?

Tags: git, ssh

```
git clone ssh://user@host:port/project_folder.git
git clone ssh://user@host:port/project_folder/origin.git
```

Hello!
I'm trying to clone remote repository 
AND always GET ERROR:

> Cloning into 'origin'... ssh: connect to host _my_host port _my_port:
>   Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

**connecting via ssh with public/private key is successfull
but in that case it asks the passphrase**

**git does not ask the passphrase**

Please, help me understand what i'm doing wrong ....(
A. git does not use ssh key?
B. git uses it, but syntax is wrong, should we specify parameter for passphrase?
C. project name is wrong? so how to get correct project name??

Remote repositary is not github project.

!!!!!!!!!
**DECISION HAS BEEN FOUND: problem is at restricted access for git remote access to this repo. Wandering, why GIT doesn't show explicit reason of such error.. THANK YOU GUYS. THANKS FOR YOUR GOOD ANSWERS, ATTENTION TO OTHER'S QUESTIONS. **

Don't know which of answers to check as decision. What do you think about it?

Comment: The `:port` part looks extremely suspicious. Can you show us the actual port number even if you don't want to reveal the full host name? Why are they running their server on a nonstandard port (if indeed they are)?

Comment: "Connection timed out" suggests that you cannot reach the server at all, so it's too early to say if there might *also* be a problem with the project path and/or your ssh key.

Comment: Are you sure they have not just turned off the server, and forgot to tell you?

Comment: @tripleee server is online, actual port number is 2233, and host is just some ip

Answer (score 1):

> It is a remote server, client have given me ssh access with ssh-keys, git repo is located in subfolder. And that repository has its own remote origin (git status). ssh connection succeeds.

If you know the path of that repo on the remote server, you can try and use, from your local machine, the URL:

```
 ssh://user@host:port/full/path/to/repo.git
```

This assume there is a bare repo at the folder `/full/path/to/repo.git` on the remote server.
And that it is accessible to the user making the remote session.

The OP confirms:

> problem is at restricted access for git remote access to this repo.

Comment: Remote repositary is not github project

Comment: @ИванДоронин Is it a remote server, or are you trying to clone a repo from your own local machine?

Comment: It is a remote server,
client have given me ssh access with ssh-keys, git repo is located in subfolder. And that repository has its own remote origin (git status).   ssh connection succeds, there i can use git commands.   Problem is that i can't clone repositary at my local machine.....   and that would be nice.

Comment: @ИванДоронин OK: I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: yes, i've tried this command, i'm suspecting, that client have restricted somehow "clone" option for anyone

Comment: @ИванДоронин But `ssh user@host:port` is working, right? I mean you can open an interactive shell session to that server?

Comment: @ИванДоронин The accessibility/restriction issue was implied in my previous comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Following might be some of the issues what you might be facing.

1. You don't have the proper access rights to the repository that your accessing.

If your a part of the project and your mentor has assigned you to that repository than only you can have an access to it.

You can easily check whether your assigned to that repository or not by typing github.com and followed by the company, group or any specific name where it is hosted.

```
https://github.com/company_name
```

Once you hit the above URL and if your able to see the project than your having the proper access to the repository or else not.

2. Once you verify from Step 1. The next thing is you have to add your public ssh key to git settings.

Navigate to your `~/.ssh` folder.

You will find **id_rsa** and **id_rsa.pub**. Sometimes you will generate more than one sha keys as you may want to collabrate for your personal git hub account other than your company.

**id_rsa.pub** is the file content that you need to copy and paste in the github settings.

You can use cat **id_rsa.pub** to see the content and copy from the command line.

Navigate to your github settings from the top right corner by click on **Settings**.

Once your on this page on left side bar click on **SSH and GPG keys** and then add your new SSH key which you had copied.

Now your all good to go with cloning the remote repository.

Comment: thank you for so detailed answer, but i have to deal with usual remote git repositary, no github.

~/.ssh   contains id_rsa and id_rsa.pub   and usual connection via ssh is successfull
(i.e. $ssh -p 1234 user@host asks only for passphrase and then connection succeeds )

Comment: In that case check which type of protocol your using in your remote git repository whether its **local** (incase in your own laptop), **http**, **ssh**. If its **http** and your doing it by ssh then it wont work

Comment: Excuse me plz, but couldn't you tell me which command to use to get enabled protocol on remote machine ?