# Downloading particular folder from github

Tags: shell, github

I want to download a particular folder from GitHub.

Currently, I am using **svn export** to download folder from GitHub.
Is there any alternative way to download folder from the specific folder?

I am running this on a node and I cannot install **svn** in my production node

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo

Comment: How on the Earth this is related to [tag:ruby] and [tag:java-8]? Removed inappropriate tags.