# How to integrate swagger ui with golang and goa

Tags: go, swagger-ui

I have been building my first RESTful service with go and goa, so basically I started doing [this](https://goa.design/learn/guide/) and at the end, goa generate two swagger files, `swagger.yaml` and `swagger.json`. The thing is that I've been looking for a way to add the swagger ui to, let's say, the index. But I haven't been able to find an example for that.

I also look in the [examples](https://github.com/goadesign/examples) and in the [design - swagger](https://goa.design/design/swagger/) section but the only suggestion that they gave me is to use the [goa swagger design](http://swagger.goa.design/) generator, but I don't know if there's a way to perform this action without the need of accessing a public host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

The [files example](https://github.com/goadesign/examples/tree/HEAD/files) shows how to build an API that serves static assets, which can be adapted to including Swager-UI.

In order to follow the example:

1. Get the dependencies
2. Add `Resource`s to the `design.go` file
3. Mount controllers in the `main.go`
4. Download and edit Swagger-UI
5. Run the generators

After this you should have a working REST-API including the Swagger-UI

### Details

<sup>(Please replace `example.com/your-package/` with the path to your package).</sup>

#### 1. Get the dependencies

In order to serve files, the example uses:

- [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/a-urth/go-bindata/) 
  <sup>Small utility which generates Go code from any file. Useful for embedding binary data in a Go program.</sup>
- [`go-bindata-assetfs`](https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/)
  <sup>Serves embedded files from `go-bindata` with `net/http`.</sup>

Get these using:

```
go get github.com/a-urth/go-bindata/...
go get github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/...
```

#### 2. Add Resources to the `design.go` file:

```
    var _ = Resource("schema", func() {
        Files("/schema/*filepath", "public/schema/")
    })

    var _ = Resource("swagger", func() {
        Files("/swagger/*filepath", "public/swagger/")
    })
```

#### 3. Mount controllers in the `main.go`

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "example.com/your-package/app"
    "example.com/your-package/public/swagger"

    "github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs"
    "github.com/goadesign/goa"
    "github.com/goadesign/goa/middleware"
)

func main() {
    // ...

    // Mount "schema" controller
    c1 := NewSchemaController(service)
    app.MountSchemaController(service, c1)
    // Mount "swagger" controller
    c2 := NewSwaggerController(service)
    // You can override FileSystem of the controller.
    // For example using github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs is like below.
    c2.FileSystem = func(dir string) http.FileSystem {
        return &assetfs.AssetFS{
            Asset:     swagger.Asset,
            AssetDir:  swagger.AssetDir,
            AssetInfo: swagger.AssetInfo,
            Prefix:    dir,
        }
    }
    app.MountSwaggerController(service, c2)

    // ...
}
```

#### 4. Download Swagger-UI

Use [your favorite method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo) to download the [`dist` folder](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) of Swagger UI.
Place all the files in the `example.com/your-package/public/swagger` folder.

In the `example.com/your-package/public/swagger/index.html` file:

- Search for `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json`
- Replace it with `./swagger.json`.
  <sup>That way the generated `swagger.json` will be used instead of the Petstore example.</sup>

#### 5. Run the generators

```
go generate goagen -d example.com/your-package/design app
go generate goagen -d example.com/your-package/design main
go generate goagen -d example.com/your-package/design swagger -o public
go generate goagen -d example.com/your-package/design schema -o public
go generate go-bindata -ignore 'bindata.go' -pkg swagger -o public/swagger/bindata.go ./public/swagger/...
```

This will create the controllers, swagger, schema and static content.

#### Done

You should now have a fully functional Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

I was running this recently and also wondered how to get the swagger ui up. Once you've generated the `openapi3.json` files, you can use this docker-compose config to bring up the swagger ui. You can replace the mounted volume and the SWAGGER_JSON variable according to where the files are. Swagger ui should run okay in http://localhost:8080.

Note: You might need to enable CORS in goa to execute the requests.

```
swagger:
  image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  environment:
    SWAGGER_JSON: '/openapi3.json'
  volumes:
    - ./gen/http/openapi3.json:/openapi3.json
```