# Git Pull But Only A Directory Not the Entire Repo

Tags: github

How to Download Only A Particular folder from GitHub.

I have a very slow Internet Connection and I am learning asp.net core.

The [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) requires code from this Link ->

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/logging/index/sample2

So If I make a Git Pull Or Just Download the [repo](https://codeload.github.com/aspnet/Docs/zip/master) its a huge 800 Mb :(

I just wan't this [little part](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/logging/index/sample2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading the zip remains the smallest archive you can download, since it does not include the full history of the repo.

And that archive does weight 780MB...

That being said, as described in "[Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879691/6309)", check if a service like **[DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home)** can help.