# downloaf only a directory on git

Tags: github

I followed ths instructions on this [answer](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-can-I-download-a-specific-folder-from-a-GitHub-repo/td-p/88).  But it still downloaded the whole repository ( the fourth line of the bellow code)

```
mkdir directoryName
cd directoryName
git init
git remote add origin -f repoUrl
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo

Comment: @Ckiller, that was it!  thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)