# Checkout github folder with svn-client, svn update not working correctly

Tags: github, svn, svn-client

I found svn client can checkout specific folder from github. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194523/8074178)

so, i did checkout github folder with svn client like below,
`svn co https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/trunk/{related path}`

and change some files under `{related path}`.
after that, i run `svn up` in working copy directory. **it works fine!!**

**but,** i did checkout like below,
`svn co https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}/{related path}`

and change some files under `{related path}`, 
and  run `svn up`, it update revision, **but did't update change files**.

why not update files?
anyone know about this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use default branch (almost `master`), use `trunk` instead of `branches/master`